# How does jsPerf determine which of the code snippets is fastest?

Tags: javascript, performance, benchmarking, jsperf

Today I visited [jsPerf](http://jsperf.com/) and now I am wondering…

1. What is "ops/sec"?
2. How many iterations does it do?
3. On what basis does it calculate which is faster? What is the formula behind these calculations?

Example: http://jsperf.com/concatenation-vs-join

Can anyone tell me?

Comment: 2. It runs each given code for a few seconds (~4 seconds)

Comment: 3. The code that has more OPS/Sec is faster (obviously) `:)`

Comment: Also, read the FAQ: http://jsperf.com/faq

Answer (score 131, accepted):

I wrote [Benchmark.js](http://benchmarkjs.com), which [jsPerf](http://jsperf.com/browse) uses.

1. "`ops/sec`" stands for operations per second.
   That is how many times a test is projected to execute in a second.
2. A test is repeatedly executed until it reaches the minimum time needed to get a [percentage uncertainty](http://spiff.rit.edu/classes/phys273/uncert/uncert.html) for the measurement of less than or equal to `1%`. The number of iterations will vary depending on the resolution of the environment’s timer and how many times a test can execute in the minimum run time. We collect completed test runs for `5` seconds *(configurable)*, or at least `5` runs *(also configurable)*, and then perform statistical analysis on the sample. So, a test may be repeated `100,000` times in `50 ms` *(the minimum run time for most environments)*, and then repeated `100` times more *(`5` seconds)*. A larger sample size *(in this example, `100`)*, leads to a smaller [margin of error](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Margin_of_error).
3. We base the decision of which test is faster on more than just ops/sec by also accounting for margin of error. For example, a test with a lower ops/sec but higher margin of error may be statistically *indistinguishable* from a test with higher ops/sec and lower margin of error.

   We used a [welch t-test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Welch%27s_t_test), similar to what [SunSpider](http://www.webkit.org/perf/sunspider/sunspider.html) uses, but switched to an [unpaired 2-sample t-test](https://github.com/mathiasbynens/Benchmark.js/blob/d4e874f2c0956d11bd1187870c2655eb3a3ab692/benchmark.js#L1175-1194) for equal variance *(the variance is extremely small)* because the welch t-test had problems comparing lower ops/sec and higher ops/sec with small variances which caused the [degrees of freedom](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degrees_of_freedom_(statistics)) to be computed as less than `1`. We also add a `5.5%` allowance on tests with similar ops/sec because real world testing showed that identical tests can swing ~`5%` from test to re-test. T-tests are used to check that differences between tests are [statistically significant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statistical_significance).

Comment: I've always wondered if when doing tests that manipulate i.e. HTML form elements, do you need to "reset" them back to defaults in order for the other tests to be fair/accurate?

Comment: @GaryHole Yes, you would need to reset everything back to the default state outside of the timed code region for it to be as accurate as possible.

Comment: What is the ±percentage inside the Ops/sec column?

Answer (score 6):

You can read **[Bulletproof JavaScript benchmarks](http://calendar.perfplanet.com/2010/bulletproof-javascript-benchmarks/)** article from the authors. It uses [Benchmark.js](http://benchmarkjs.com/) btw, which is Open Source.