# Explain this JsPerf.com result

Tags: javascript, benchmarking, performance, jsperf

I ran a test on this website 
http://jsperf.com/

[image: This is screen shot of a jsperf test i ran]

I want some one to explain

1. What does green and pink signifies
2. What is ops per second
3. what is 95,814,583
4. what is +- 1.95% is
5. whats does 'fastest' and 'slower' means

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Hey, I’m the creator of jsPerf.

1. The fastest test(s) get a green background. The slowest test(s) get a pink/red background.
2. See below.
3. It means the test can run about 95,814,583 times a second.
4. ± 1.95 is the margin of error. (For more info, see below.)
5. “fastest” means this is the fastest test in the test case. 19% slower means this test is 19% slower than the fastest test in the test case.

See [John-David Dalton’s answer to “How does jsPerf work?”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4986245/how-does-jsperf-work/4996963#4996963) for a detailed explanation of the following:

- What is “ops/sec”?
- How many iterations does it do?
- On what basis does it calculate which is faster?
- What is the formula behind these calculations?

Comment: do you have an RSS feed on the tag `jsperf` so you can answer them quickly?

Comment: @Raynos: “jsPerf” is one of my saved searches on Twitter. A bot auto-tweeted a link to this question, so I answered it :)

Comment: @MathiasBynens How should I intepret the results when `Infinity ±0.00% fastest` appears?