# vars on the first parameter of loops

Tags: javascript

I am aware that I can simplify:

```
var a;
var b;
```

into:

```
var a, b;
```

But can I do the same on loops?

```
for(var a=0,b=0;a<3;a++){
    //code
}
```

Or I need to write `var a=0, var b=0`?

Comment: why not just try and see? http://jsfiddle.net/gKjJv/

Comment: why don't you test it yourself.a simple 2 lines code will give you answer

Comment: I don't know how. And don't make me open another question saying "how can I test if the 'b' in `for(var a,b;a<3;a++){}` is defined

Comment: @TuxedoKnight Chess there is this black magic called [jslint](http://www.jslint.com/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`for(var a=0,b=0;a<3;a++)` is fine.

Answer (score 0):

it is perfectly valid javascript and it will work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Yes,you can do like that. Just check it.

Answer (score 0):

`for(var a=0,b=0;a<3;a++)` In other programming languages like C/C++ it is widely used. There is no need to use `var` twice - you've already stated that you are declaring variables with the first one.

You can also use (not a good practice):

```
var a = x, b = y; // or var a = x; var b = y;
for ( ; a < b; a++) {
   //code
}
```

This is mostly used when the `length` property is used. Thus not calling it on every iteration. Here is a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6973942/is-optimizing-javascript-for-loops-really-necessary), [jsperf test](http://jsperf.com/for-vs-length), [jsperf test](http://jsperf.com/loop-iteration-length-comparison-variations).

```
for(var i = 0, len = obj.length; i < len; i++) {
    //code
}
```

Comment: @TuxedoKnightChess - Huh? This answers your question and then goes on to give a practical example - why would you want to downvote it?

Answer (score 0):

The syntax for using `var` in the initialisation part of a `for` statement is the same as using `var` elsewhere. So the following will work fine:

```
for(var a=0,b=0; a<3; a++){ }
```

Note that this does **not** limit the scope of variables declared like that to just the `for` statement's block as would happen in some other languages. JavaScript has only global and function scope, *not* block scope. The `a` and `b` variables declared in the example above will be accessible anywhere in the current scope (including *above* the `for` statement, though the values will be undefined).

Note also that you can't say:

```
for(var a=0; var b=0; a<3; a++) { }
```

(If you want to declare multiple variables in the `for` statement's initialisation expression you need to use the comma syntax.)