# Why save the array length to a variable before using for(;i<len;)?

Tags: javascript, variables, for-loop

I am learning JavaScript and I see in some books/tutorial this:

```
myvariable = myArray.length;
for(i = 0; i < myVariable; i++){
    doSomething;
}
```

What's the difference if I write it like this (I mean if I don't create a variable that holds the length of my array and I use `myArray.length` Directly in the `for` loop.

```
for(i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++)
{
    doSomething;
}
```

Which one is better?

P.S: sorry for my bad English it's not my native language.

Thank you.

Comment: The second way is considered better since you don't waste a line. To your question there isn't a difference. @Chuck: No it's not. He asked about functionality not about performance.

Comment: This question is *not* a duplicate of "Speed and memory benefit from declaring variable outside JavaScript loop?" - there is only one scope, no anonymous/HoF functions, etc.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek: I do agree that I chose the wrong question from the list of duplicates for the reason user2864740 mentioned, but OP did not ask about functionality. The question was "Which is better?" It is definitely a duplicate question, at any rate.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17989270/javascript-for-loop-performance-storing-array-length-in-a-variable , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12796887/for-loop-performance-in-javascript - some of these answer are focused on "performance", but there is also useful information which I think will cover your questions. (I use the form *without* the variable for a simple iteration over an array, due to habit/preference and following the 97/3 rule.)

Comment: Yep, that "duplicate" was completely irrelevant. Reopened.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no functional difference with the given code.

There is a slight performance difference (negligible in most cases) in how you declare the variables that are in the `for` statement.

When doing this:

```
for(var i = 0; i < someArray.length; i++)
```

`var i` and `someArray.length` are evaluated every iteration. So the total time, `d`, it take the loop to occur is the time, `t`, it takes to evaluate a variable, multiplied by the number of iterations, `i`, of your loop:

```
d = t*i
```

Thus, as stated early, this difference will be negligible in most cases. It takes less code to write it the first way, but doing it this way will lower `d`:

```
var i = 0,
    len = someArray.length;

for( ; i<len; i++)
```

However, sometimes evaluating the length of `someArray` every iteration is necessary due to possible changes in the length of `someArray` (for example, when removing elements from `someArray`):

```
for(var i = 0; i<someArray.length; i++) {
    someArray.splice(someArray.length - 1, 1);
}
```

This will remove the last element of `someArray`, and if you don't recompute the length of `someArray` for every iteration of the loop, some browsers will throw an error.

---

To see some examples of how you can write the same loop in many different ways (as well as see the performance differences), see this [jsperf](http://jsperf.com/loops/70) (a JavaScript performance test).

Comment: @user2864740, What would be a better way to say it? Is it just recomputed every time? (Thus, taking into consideration the time it takes to recompute the variable?)

Comment: @user2864740, thanks, updated my answer to reflect your comment.

Comment: I would say that the [test expression](http://es5.github.io/#x12.6.3) is *evaluated* each loop. While evaluating `i<len` or `i<someArray.length` for a fixed-size array are functionally equivalent (and as noted have little-to-no consequential performance impact), this evaluation can be expanded to discuss expressions such as `f(i)` (e.g. maybe computationally expensive or with side-effects) or `i<someArray.length` for a *changing-sized* array (as demonstrated).

Answer (score 0):

Approved answer is wrong. There is actually a slight performance advantage to **not** storing length in a variable because the storing statement operation creates an overhead.

Also note that ES6 offers for/of which has better syntax when you don't need the array index but that one is significantly slower.

See the comparison here https://jsperf.com/storing-length/1

I'm comparing 3 different versions:

```
 function f1(arr) {
    let l = arr.length, res=0;
    for(let i=0; i < l; i++) res+=arr[i];
    return res;
  }

  function f2(arr) {
    let res=0;
    for(let i=0; i< arr.length; i++) res+=arr[i];
    return res;
  }

  function f3(arr) {
    let res=0;
    for(const a of arr) res+=a;
    return res;
  }
```

When using a large sample, f1 is ~20% slower than f2, f3 is ~60% slower.