# For Loop optimization in Javascript

Tags: javascript, performance, memory, optimization, for-loop

So i have been taking a Computer science course that uses C+ to teach programming concepts with.  today i learned a new concept that i was not sure applied to JS, in which there are system resources expended each time a string.length is calculated.  It seems like a tiny matter but it got me thinking about huge arrays and how that could add up.  Check out this example and let me know if loop #2 is indeed more efficient than the first and thanks:

```
var weekDay = ["Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday"];

//for loop #1
for(i=0; i<weekDay.length; i++){
 //code code code
;}

//for loop #2
for(i=0; var n=weekDay.length; i<n; i++){
 //code code code
;}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The second approach is faster, but not by much. Also, there is a small syntax error

```
for( var i = 0, n = weekDay.length; i < n; i++ ){ ... }
```

This is rather common in javascript code. Please note the importance in declaring all of your variables with `var` so that they do not step on the wrong scope.

You can see this js performance test here: http://jsperf.com/forloopiterator which shows the results being 24% faster when using the second approach.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, [**premature optimization is the root of all evil**](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization).

Secondly; you are completely correct that loop #2 is more efficient.

Loop #1 would do calculate the length of `weekDay` for *every* iteration of the loop. This means it would calculate the length 10,000 times in a 10,000 length array.

Loop #2 would calculate the length of `weekDay` and set the variable `n` to be the result, and hence we keep the length in a variable rather than recalculating it for every iteration.

[**Read more about why premature optimization is bad**](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/80084/is-premature-optimization-really-the-root-of-all-evil).

Comment: Technically array.length doesn't calculate the length. The length is calculated per addition / deletion so .length only gets the stored value.

Answer (score 0):

This question has been asked a few times...
[Is optimizing JavaScript for loops really necessary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6973942/is-optimizing-javascript-for-loops-really-necessary)

I found the following link very helpful. Basically it depends on browser version and vendor.

In some cases e.g. IE yes #2 is much faster

http://jsperf.com/loop-iteration-length-comparison-variations

Answer (score 0):

I would always pre-cache the length explicity, i.e.

```
var n = weekDay.length;
var i;
for(i=0;i<n; i++){ 
do_something;
}
```

A much clearer approach, as all variables definitions are 'hoisted' to the top of the function anyway.