# Best way to create new DOM elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

Using jquery is it better to create a DOM element like this:-

```
function create(options)
{
     $('<form action="' + options.action + '"></form>');    
}
```

Or like this:

```
function create(options)
{
     $form = $('<form></form>');
     $form.attr('action',options.action); 
}
```

This may be a matter of opinion. I feel that the second way gives more clarity but I suspect it is less efficient...

Comment: This is called micro-optimization, also know as "the root of all evil".

Comment: @Juhana: You're thinking of premature optimization. I don't know why asking about methods of DOM element construction would be considered premature, or even mirco, optimization. From the question... *"I feel that the second way gives more clarity..."*

Comment: *"...but I suspect it is less efficient."* I think it's safe to say that he's not asking because he's pinpointed this issue to be the performance bottleneck in his code.

Comment: @Juhana: He's asking if one is conceptually better than the others, and is including clarity as a factor. No, the code probably isn't a bottleneck, which means that performance is not his greatest concern, which means this question isn't all about optimization. That said, **not all optimization is "evil"**. If you can gain even a tiny optimization, and not obscure the meaning of the code, why wouldn't you do it? The "evil" of *premature* optimization comes from introducing unnecessary bugs, or obscuring the meaning of the code for the sake of marginal gain. Clearly that's not an issue here.

Comment: The first code is vulnerable to HTML injection.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

jQuery can create object as following code

```
$form = $('<form>', {action: 'my action'});
```

`class` is a reserved word in IE and needs to be quoted. See full list of reserved words: [Reserved Keywords in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/a/147776/887539)

Comment: +1 Beat me to it. Although you should always include the closing tag as some (now outdated) browsers won't add this automatically: Eg. `$('<form></form>', {action: 'my action'});`

Comment: not only outdated. Had a problem with IE8 about not closed `form`-tag, you can do it like this `$('<form/>')`

Comment: I'd class IE8 as outdated personally :D

Comment: [$('<element>') vs $('<element></element>')](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/268490/jquery-document-createelement-equivalent)

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan: Closing tag isn't necessary if you're not including attributes or content. jQuery will use `document.createElement()` whether you do `$('<form>')`, `$('<form/>')` or `$('<form></form>')`

Comment: Pefect - this way performed very well on the benchmark by @AndreasAL and it's good and clear. Thankyou!

Comment: I wonder if it'll be even faster if you cache the `<form>` first, then `.clone()` it. i.e. `var form = $('<form>'); form.clone().attr({ action : 'my action' });`

Comment: `update: attr class must be quoted (bug in IE)` === `reserved word in IE`

Answer (score 39):

[Check this](http://jsperf.com/create-dom-element) to find out for your self.

[image: Creating DOM notes using jQuery]
Note higher is better [(OPS/Sec = operations per second = how many times per second the given code executes)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4986245/how-does-jsperf-work)

And the test winner in every other browser than **Opera**:

```
var form = document.createElement("form"),
    $form = $(form);
form.action = options.action;
```

---

**NOTE:**

the native method will be even faster if you don't need a **jQuery** object:

```
var form = document.createElement("form");
form.action = options.action;
```

Comment: +1 If there's any concern about performance *and* clarity, this would take care of both.

Comment: +1 I didn't know about jsperf.com - that's very neat, thanks for the introduction!

Comment: +1 for jsPerf and suggesting no jQuery. People tend to do everything with jQuery, they should know when it is better or not.

Answer (score 4):

I always do the second one.

```
function create(options)
{
     $form = $('<form></form>');
     $form.attr('action',options.action); 
}
```

I prefer this method simply because it find it more readable.

Answer (score 3):

Never hurts to optimize...until it does...you could use straight up JS:

```
function create(options)
{
  var newform = document.createElement('form');

  newform.setAttribute('action',options.action);
}
```

Aside from that it's negligible as mentionned above, whatever is easier to read for you...i.e. option 2

Answer (score 1):

Unless you are running this function many times, any performance difference will be negligible. So I would always go with the clearest, easiest to update solution (i.e. the second one.)

Comment: @NateBarbettini Sounds very much like an answer to me?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about the actual underlining code of jquery and cannot tell which one has better performance.

Anyway as I can imagine, in the first case jquery will parse attributes anyway and sets values to them, so there should not be big performance difference.

So I think the first solution is more convenient if it contains a lot of html code, otherwise I will prefer second one.