# What do the results from benchmark js mean?

Tags: javascript, benchmark.js

I am using a version of Benchmark JS for node and I can't find any information about how to read the results.

Firstly, is there a place that details what all the data you can extract from Benchmark JS?

Secondly I am currently getting the following result in my console:

```
Test x 2,276,094 ops/sec ±0.84% (190 runs sampled)
```

What do all these bits of information mean?

**Test**: the name of my test, I know that one

**x 2,276,094 ops/sec**: I am assuming this is the average number of times the code could theoretically run in a second?

**±0.84%**: No idea

**190 runs sampled**: The amount of times benchmark ran the code to get the result?

Comment: The author of Benchmark JS explains it nicely in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4996963/511529).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Your question probably isn't a duplicate, but amusingly [the answer to it is](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4996963/511529) as [GolezTroi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/511529/goleztrol) points out in [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28524653/what-do-the-results-from-benchmark-js-mean/28524734#comment45365324_28524653).

In case that question is deleted (highly unlikely), here's the full text of [John-David Dalton](https://stackoverflow.com/users/166625/john-david-dalton)'s answer:

> I wrote [Benchmark.js](http://benchmarkjs.com), which [jsPerf](http://jsperf.com/browse) uses.
>
> 1. "`ops/sec`" stands for operations per second.
>    That is how many times a test is projected to execute in a second.
> 2. A test is repeatedly executed until it reaches the minimum time needed to get a [percentage uncertainty](http://spiff.rit.edu/classes/phys273/uncert/uncert.html) for the measurement of less than or equal to `1%`. The number of iterations will vary depending on the resolution of the environment’s timer and how many times a test can execute in the minimum run time. We collect completed test runs for `5` seconds *(configurable)*, or at least `5` runs *(also configurable)*, and then perform statistical analysis on the sample. So, a test may be repeated `100,000` times in `50 ms` *(the minimum run time for most environments)*, and then repeated `100` times more *(`5` seconds)*. A larger sample size *(in this example, `100`)*, leads to a smaller [margin of error](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Margin_of_error).
> 3. We base the decision of which test is faster on more than just ops/sec by also accounting for margin of error. For example, a test with a lower ops/sec but higher margin of error may be statistically *indistinguishable* from a test with higher ops/sec and lower margin of error.
>
>    We used a [welch t-test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Welch%27s_t_test), similar to what [SunSpider](http://www.webkit.org/perf/sunspider/sunspider.html) uses, but switched to an [unpaired 2-sample t-test](https://github.com/mathiasbynens/Benchmark.js/blob/d4e874f2c0956d11bd1187870c2655eb3a3ab692/benchmark.js#L1175-1194) for equal variance *(the variance is extremely small)* because the welch t-test had problems comparing lower ops/sec and higher ops/sec with small variances which caused the [degrees of freedom](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degrees_of_freedom_(statistics)) to be computed as less than `1`. We also add a `5.5%` allowance on tests with similar ops/sec because real world testing showed that identical tests can swing ~`5%` from test to re-test. T-tests are used to check that differences between tests are [statistically significant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statistical_significance).

Comment: Thanks @TJCrowder I now have a much better understanding of Benchmark