# Alternative for ParentNode.replaceChildren

Tags: javascript

I just figured, that ParentNode.replaceChildren() won't work in older browsers, for example chrome. How can I re-write it basically?

```
ModalBody.replaceChildren(loader);
```

Comment: Hi! Please take the [tour] (you get a badge!) and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Your best bet here is to do your research, [search](/help/searching) for related topics on SO, and give it a go. ***If*** you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [mcve] of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help.

Comment: You'd probably use a combination of [`replaceChild`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/replaceChild), [`insertAdjacentHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML), and [`insertBefore`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/insertBefore).

Comment: https://caniuse.com/?search=replaceChildren

Comment: @mplungjan - I think the OP means "older versions of Chrome" since it was just added in v86.

Comment: I know - I just wanted to save ppl from having to look it up since it is missing from MDNs page.
I would think innerHTML would do the job very well in all cases where there are no event handlers on the children

Comment: Unfortunately there are events on children ....

Comment: Maybe this does help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4991098/replacing-all-children-of-an-htmlelement

Comment: @KatharinaSchreiber what is `loader` - can you please make a [mcve] using the `[<>]` snippet editor

Answer (score 1):

Remove children of **ModalBody**

```
const parent = document.getElementById("parent");
parent.innerHTML = '';
```

And then add the **loader**

```
parent.innerHTML = loader
```

```js
const button = document.querySelector("button")
button.onclick = () => {
  // Remove all children of the first, ModalBody
  const first = document.getElementById("first")
  first.innerHTML = ""

  // Add loader
  const second = document.getElementById("second")
  first.innerHTML = second.innerHTML // loader
}
```

```html
<div id="first">
  <p>A</p>
  <p>B</p>
  <p>C</p>
  <p>D</p>
  <p>E</p>
  <p>F</p>
  <p>G</p>
</div>


<div id="second">
  <p>Loader</p>
</div>

<button>Replace</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Depends how far back you want to support

```
function my_replaceChildren(el, nodes) {
  if (el.replaceChildren)
    return el.replaceChildren(...nodes); // supported Chrome 86+

  el.innerHTML = "";
  el.append( ...nodes);
}
```

**https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/append**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can remove all children from the element and append the new ones:

```js
function replaceChildren(el, ...children){
    el.textContent = '';
    for(let child of children){
        el.appendChild(child);
    }
}
```

If you are not using a transpiler you will need to make this code compatible with browsers you need to support:

```js
function replaceChildren(el){
    var children = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1);
    el.textContent = '';
    for(var i = 0; i< children.length; i++){
        el.appendChild(children[i]);
    }
}
```

You can take a look at [caniuse](https://caniuse.com/dom-manip-convenience) for browser support data.

Answer (score 0):

I don't why, but this worked:

```
ModalBody.insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', loader.outerHTML);
```

Basically here is what I have connected to loader:

```
var loader = document.createElement('div');
loader.classList.add('loader');
loader.classList.add('is-loading');
loader.classList.add('mt-5');
```

So, when I tried this

```
ModalBody.insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', loader);
```

instead of getting the moving circle as a sign that content is being loaded, I got [object HTMLDivElement] in my modal instead, which after a couple of seconds was replaced by the right content. So somehow **.outerHTML** on loader fixed it. I am still new to all this. Maybe someone can explan why it works this way?