# Howto delete everything inside <html> using pure javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm searching a js one-liner to delete everything inside the `<html>` Tag.

I want to remove the `<head>`, the `<body>` and everything else declared outside those.

Comment: Why? You would then not be able to do anything, as the JS will be gone too.

Comment: Would that not put it in an infinite loop...?

Comment: maybe try to use ajax to load some php script that will remove everyhting

Comment: Why not? ;) I want to make a Chrome Extension and all it does is to remove everything inside the Webpage.

Comment: @ChrisW no it wouldn't because the script will be injected by my Browser Extension.

Comment: -1 What have you tried? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3955229/remove-all-child-elements-of-a-dom-node-in-javascript

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`document.write()` will create empty page, or actually the following code:

```
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body></body>
</html>
```

But I am not sure if this won't clash if the code will be in external file

Answer (score 3):

It's not an oneliner, but it does the job you're asking for.

```
document.open();
document.write("");
document.close();
```

Comment: No need to open and close the document. Simply calling document.write(), as @Zefiryn mentioned, does the trick. Thanks for your answer

Comment: @John It may appear to work, but I've had problems without using `open` and `close`...which is possible that you may not encounter.

Comment: It'll maybe work "perfectly fine" in context of a Chrome Extension script (I can't tell about that from experience; for instance, perhaps Chrome has already implicitly done `document.open()` for you), but it'll not reliably work in context of a normal JS function/script, at least not if you want to keep it cross browser compatible.

Comment: Ah, many thanks for pointing this out @BalusC ! I'm only using this in context of a Chrome Extension.

Answer (score 2):

1 liner :)

```
window.onload = function(){ document.getElementsByTagName("html")[0].innerHTML = "";};
```

Answer (score 0):

Once your HTML page is loaded, the javascript is loaded into the browser memory. So if you are to load jQuery for instance, you can simply call;

```
$('html').empty();
```

Give it a try using Google Chrome's Javascript Console. Type the above code, then you can still access jQuery and manipulate the DOM.

**Edit**

To answer your comment John. You have not stated in your question that jQuery cannot be used.

Comment: +1 Also, @John, almost *everywhere* on SO, where a library is disallowed, it's explicitly stated in the question. Simply saying "js" doesn't presume "vanilla EMCAScript".

Comment: @msanford unfortunately some people do not know how to construct a good question and others Down vote without thinking. Thanks for +1!

Answer (score -1):

Not really a good idea, but this worked for me.

First, wrap all the elements in a div element with a id.

I made a div with the id `wrapper`.

Then:

```js
let doc = document.getElementById("wrapper");
doc.innerHTML = "";
```