# no of input fields according to user input

Tags: javascript

I have a form that will ask number of input fields from user, and then append inputs to the form. I have developed the function using JavaScript.

The problem is for the first time it will work fine. If I again select another number from the select tag, it will append the number of input fields to the previous inputs.

Example:

- If I first select 4 input fields it will show 4 input fields.
- If I again select 2 from the select tag it will add another two input
  fields.

So altogether 6 input fields. I don't want that. If I select 4 it should be 4. If I again select 2 it should be 2, not 6. Here is my code:

```
function obj(){

    var a=document.getElementById('no_of_obj').value; //select tag value(1 to 6)
    var b=document.getElementById('objBlock') //this is the container
    var i=0;

    while(i<a){
        var txt=document.createElement('input');
        txt.type="text";
        txt.id="obj"+i;
        txt.style.height="30px";

        b.appendChild(txt);
        i++;
    }

}
```

Comment: You're doing fine so far, you just need to use `removeChild` (probably looking up the inputs via the `id` you've assigned them) when you're removing inputs. E.g., know how many you already have, and if the number is now fewer, remove rather than adding. There's no trick to it, you just have to write the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
function obj(){

    var a=document.getElementById('no_of_obj').value;//select tag value(1 to 6)
    var b=document.getElementById('objBlock')//this is the container
    var i=0;

    while(b.children.length < a){
        var ct = document.createElement('div');
        var txt=document.createElement('input');
        txt.type="text";
        txt.id="obj"+i;
        txt.style.height="30px";
        ct.appendChild(txt);
        b.appendChild(ct)
    }

    while(b.children.length > a){
        b.removeChild(b.children[b.children.length - 1]);
    }
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/UxQAs/2/)

Using jQuery

```
$(function(){
    var $ct = $('#objBlock');
    $('#no_of_obj').change(function(){
        var count = $(this).val(), counter = count - $ct.children().length;

        while(counter-- > 0){
            $('<div><input class="input-xlarge"/></div>').appendTo($ct);
        }

        $ct.children(':gt(' + (count - 1) + ')').remove();
    });
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/UxQAs/4/)

Comment: i want to add a css class for every element.but the following code is giving a error           txt.class="input-xlarge";

Comment: it should be `txt.className="input-xlarge"`

Comment: thanx it worked.how can implement the same functionality in jquery

Comment: thnx  Arun P Johny it is what exactly i was looking for!

Answer (score 3):

You could clear down the `objBlock` container before appending the new `input` elements, using:

```
b.innerHTML = '';
```

Comment: This will, of course, wipe out any values the user has typed in the first two fields which are meant to be retained. (Which may or may not be okay.)

Comment: thanks Simon Adcock it worked fine.but the input fields coming in one row.probably i should include a <br/> tag after every input.how can i do that?

Comment: Yep, something like `var br=document.createElement('br');` and then `b.appendChild(br);`?

Comment: No problem :) Please feel free to mark this as answered, if it has solved your problem.

Comment: still one problem  b.innerHTML = ''; is wiping out values the user has typed in the previous fields.i want to retain them.

Comment: I see, in which case you're probably better off assigning an id to each input field and using the `removeChild` method suggested by @T.J.Crowder See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3955229/remove-all-child-elements-of-a-dom-node-in-javascript)

Comment: i think the method by  Arun P Johny  (demo is here http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/UxQAs/2/) is same as @T.J.Crowder suggested!