# Copy Divs using Javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, label

I have 2 diferent divs: [Div1] and [Div2].
My goal is that when i click on some event, i want [Div1] to be the exactly the same as the [Div2].
I used this code:

```
 document.getElementById("div1")=document.getElementById("div2");
```

This is a javascript error and i dont know how to do anything like this.
I cant copy every element cuz those might change based on the users actions.
I found something about cloning a node but i couldn't put it to work.
Any sugestions?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.cloneNode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well depending on what you mean by "exactly the same" (sharing the same reference? duplication of values?), you might want to try cloning:

Try:

```
var node = document.getElementById("div2");
var node2 = node.cloneNode(true); //creates deep clone with events you can do something with

///Or you could just copy the markup over
document.getElementById("div1").innerHTML = node2.innerHTML;
```

Comment: its exatly that that im trying but im not getting the same values, im getting both the div1 and div2 values (instead of only the new ones)

Comment: Not entirely sure what you're after, maybe you can post more code?

Comment: Try cleaning div1 first: [Remove all child elements of a DOM node in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3955229/remove-all-child-elements-of-a-dom-node-in-javascript).

Comment: Thanks Filipe that was the mistake. Sorry for such a amateur error and thanks for all the help

Answer (score 0):

Use jquery instead; when the user clicks the button/any action, use the following snippet:

```
$("div1").html($("div2").html());
```