# removing/deleting all the child elements in a html form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hello all I have a form and some 20 input elements inside it, On a particular event i want to remove all the elements inside it. I don't want to use remove()/removeChild() as i have to get each and every element and say remove. is there any way using which we can just remove all the elements in a form. please help

Comment: I found similar question and the answer is [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3955229/remove-all-child-elements-of-a-dom-node-in-javascript?answertab=active#tab-top). You can also read [this link](http://blog.matt.thomm.es/post/63915071626/removing-all-child-nodes-from-an-element) for more help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just empty the form using [.empty()](http://api.jquery.com/empty/)

```
$('form').empty()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('form').empty();
```

reference **[empty()](http://api.jquery.com/empty/)**

Answer (score 0):

Try this   :       `$('form').hide();`

Answer (score 0):

you can set to empty string

```
 $('form').html('')
```