# Only refreshing a single select / option HTML Object

Tags: javascript, html

I have a  object in my HTML site which I expand/add to with a little JavaScript bit (below) on button click.

Can I refresh the dropdown/select on it's own to show the new choices automaticaly or can I only do that via a whole page refresh?

```
<select name="Auswahl", id='s'> </select>
<script>
    var select = document.getElementById("s");  
    for (j = 1; j <= i; ++j){
        var opt = document.createElement('option');
        opt.value = opt.text = j;       
        select.add(opt);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: both... but you need to give more info, for example where does this info come from?  are you asp? php?

Comment: Just using JavaScript and HTML. The options are added via Button Clicks, so after each Button click I'd need it to refresh.

Comment: you can do the entire thing in js.

Comment: You should remove the comma in between the properties of your `select`.

Comment: Removed the comma, thanks, didn't notice that one.
@ T McKeown: How? So far I only found how get to refresh the whole page, didn't find out how to refresh that single object.

Answer (score 0):

you can create a function to remove all child `<option>` nodes and assign that function to a button call Reset for example, that will remove all options in the drop down list.

[Remove all child elements of a DOM node in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3955229/remove-all-child-elements-of-a-dom-node-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

Yes u can change without refresh hole page. It easy with jquery and ajax, just google them.