# How to stop the days in appending after I select the month

Tags: javascript, jquery

To make the issue short. I have 3 dropdowns for picking a date. The date picker display the range of the days within the month if it's only 29 or 31 days. It's working fine now except that when I changed in different month the value in my days is repeating.

For example I choose February. The days that is display is 28 days.
     Then I changed to March. The days displays as 31 days. The problem is they are only combining so the value in my day dropdown become many. How can I fixed this, any help?

```js
function daysInMonth(month, year) {
    return new Date(year, month, 0).getDate();
}
function onMonthChange(){
    var year = document.getElementById("yeardialog").value;
    var month = document.getElementById("monthdialog").value;
 
    var endOfTheMonth = daysInMonth(month, year);
    console.log(endOfTheMonth);
  
    var select = document.getElementById('datedialog');
    for (var i = 0; i < endOfTheMonth; i++) {
        select.options[select.options.length] = new Option(i + 1, i);
    } 
}
```

```html
<select id="yeardialog" name="yeardialog">
    <option value="">--</option>
    <option value="1990">1990</option>
    <option value="1991">1991</option>
    <option value="1992">1992</option>
</select>

<select id="monthdialog" onchange="onMonthChange()">
    <option value="">--</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
</select>

<select id="datedialog">
    <option></option>
</select>
```

Comment: have you considered http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/input.date.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var select = document.getElementById('datedialog');
select.innerHTML = ""; // clear the select.
for (var i = 0; i < endOfTheMonth; i++) {
    select.options[select.options.length] = new Option(i + 1, i);
}
```

The solution is plain and simple. Delete the contents of the select before populating them.

Solution inside the snippet:

```js
function daysInMonth(month, year) {
    return new Date(year, month, 0).getDate();
}
function onMonthChange(){
    var year = document.getElementById("yeardialog").value;
    var month = document.getElementById("monthdialog").value;
 
    var endOfTheMonth = daysInMonth(month, year);
    console.log(endOfTheMonth);

    var select = document.getElementById('datedialog');
    var selectedvalue = select.querySelector('option:checked');
    if (selectedvalue)
    {
      var store = selectedvalue.getAttribute("value");
    }
    select.innerHTML = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < endOfTheMonth; i++) {
        select.options[select.options.length] = new Option(i + 1, i);
    } 
    var retrieved = select.querySelector("option[value='"+store+"']");
    if (retrieved)
    {
      retrieved.setAttribute("selected", "true");
    }
}
```

```html
<select id="yeardialog" name="yeardialog">
    <option value="">--</option>
    <option value="1990">1990</option>
    <option value="1991">1991</option>
    <option value="1992">1992</option>
</select>

<select id="monthdialog" onchange="onMonthChange()">
    <option value="">--</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
</select>

<select id="datedialog">
    <option></option>
</select>
```

Updated question. Store the original value before deleting:

We look for the selected value using:

`select.querySelector('option:checked');`

Then we look if the value can be found in the new list. If so select the value. If not revert to `1`. This happens when you select `31` and the month loaded only has 30 days.

Comment: yeah I already tried that before to clear the select but it's resets the value in 1. For e.g I already choose a day(26) then when I choose another month the day i choose is reset

Comment: Well, that's the actual question then!

Comment: ahm I think it is still resetting the value. I choose the day 27 then I changed to another month. The day I selected is reset to 1. I want  to stay at 27. :-(

Comment: It's working now. I clear all the cache and history in my browser :-) . Thank u very much for your kindness

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't modify the `innerHTML`, I prefer removing the nodes

```
var select = document.getElementById('datedialog');

while(select.hasChildNodes())select.removeChild(select.firstChild);// clear the select.
for (var i = 0; i < endOfTheMonth; i++) {
    select.options.add(new Option(i + 1, i));
}
```

Comment: Nice but unfortunetly there are two loops in that solution.

Comment: @Tomasz http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3955229/remove-all-child-elements-of-a-dom-node-in-javascript

Comment: You're right. I've just tested that. Upvote from me. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
function onMonthChange(){
 var year = document.getElementById("yeardialog").value;
 var month = document.getElementById("monthdialog").value;

 var endOfTheMonth = daysInMonth(month, year);
 console.log(endOfTheMonth);

 var select = document.getElementById('datedialog');
 select.innerHTML = '';
 select.options[0] = new Option("Pick a date", 0);
 for (var i = 1; i < endOfTheMonth; i++) {
  select.options[select.options.length] = new Option(i + 1, i);
 }
}
```