# for...in loop not looping through all properties?

Tags: javascript, for-loop, for-in-loop, nodelist

When I load my page, a nodeList gets created, and it looks like this:

```
[text, h4, text, span, br, input, br, span, br, input, br, span, br, input, br, span, br, input, br]
```

I created a simple `for` loop that loops through all these elements and deletes each one of them from the DOM. (all the elements are in a `<section>`)

Here's the loop:

```
        for(element in videoTitlesElement.childNodes){
            if(!isNaN(element)){
                videoTitlesElement.removeChild(
                        videoTitlesElement.childNodes[element]);
            }
        }
```

But, by the end of the loop, the nodeList looks like this:

```
[h4, span, input, span, input, span, input, span, input]
```

not all elements got removed. Why?

Thanks.

Comment: Because you are modifying the collection when looping through it. Let's say you have three elements in a collection `[A, B, C]`. A `for..in` loop will internally have an indexer to keep track of the current element. So the indexer is 0 at start which points to element `A`. Then you remove the first element and the second element, `B`, now becomes the first. The indexer is now advanced and points to 1. Now the element at index 1, `C`, is removed. And as you might see the element at index 0, `B`, is untouched and skipped over.

Comment: Related: [Strange behavior when iterating over HTMLCollection from getElementsByClassName](/q/15562484/4642212).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Two things. First, don't use `for ... in` when you're iterating through numeric indexes; use a plain `for` loop. Then you won't need that `isNaN()` check, and it's generally safer.

The second problem is that when you remove a child, you change the length of the list. If you remove child 0, then the child that used to be child 1 becomes child 0.  Thus, what you *really* want is a simple `while` loop:

```
while (videoTitlesElement.childNodes.length)
  videoTitlesElement.removeChild(videoTitlesElement.childNodes[0]);
```

or, simpler:

```
while (videoTitlesElement.firstChild)
  videoTitlesElement.removeChild(videoTitlesElement.firstChild);
```

I should also note (assuming you're working with an HTML DOM) that it's easier to clear out all the child nodes of an element by simply blasting it via `.innerHTML`:

```
videoTitlesElement.innerHTML = "";
```

Comment: The simpler case is almost correct, but here: `.removeChild(firstChild)` the `firstChild` is undefined.

Comment: Thank you! Great explanation. "Clearing" the .innerHTML isn't the best in my case, and I also read that removing elements one by one is generally a lot faster.

Comment: @aCodingN00b I would be very surprised to learn that removing nodes one by one is faster than just clearing `.innerHTML`.

Comment: @Pointy http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3955229/remove-all-child-elements-of-a-dom-node-in-javascript

Comment: @aCodingN00b That question is old and I don't believe most of those comments.

Comment: @StriplingWarrior I'm not sure I trust the original revision of that test; it's a hard thing to measure because it's hard to avoid counting the cost of rebuilding the DOM after clearing it on each test iteration.

Comment: @Pointy: Good point. I suppose the performance difference is unlikely to be noticeable either way.

Answer (score 4):

The list being iterated over (`videoTitlesElement.childNodes`) is being mutated during iteration. Try iterating over a copy of the original list:

```
var children = [].slice.call(videoTitlesElement.childNodes);

for(element in children){
    if(!isNaN(element)){
         videoTitlesElement.removeChild(videoTitlesElement.childNodes[element]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that using `for..in` to iterate over arrays is frowned upon.

Answer (score 3):

If you look at your results, you'll note that you're skipping every second item.

If you imagine this as a `for` loop with an iterator, you're incrementing your iterator each time, but removing an item from the same collection before incrementing again. That means the item that was at index `1` when you first start the loop is at index `0` after you remove the first item in the array. So when you go to look at index `1` you've skipped over that element. This continues until the end of the loop, so you miss every second item.