# Why delete operator operator does not delete properties of NodeList class?

Tags: javascript, foreach, callback

In the below code,

```
<form action="javascript:void(0)" method="GET" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <fieldset>
                <legend>Details</legend>
                Enter the name: <input id="name" name="name" type="text" size="30"
                                onblur="isTheValueValid(this, document.getElementById('name_help'));">  
                <span id="name_help"></span>
                <br>
            </fieldset> 
        </form>
```

---

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            function deleteAllChildren(spanElementObject){
                if(spanElementObject != null){
                        var nodeList = spanElementObject.childNodes;
                        [].forEach.call(nodeList,function(property){
                            delete property;
                        }); 
                }
            }
            function editSpanElementText(regex, inputElementValue, spanElementObject, helpMessage){
                deleteAllChildren(spanElementObject);
                if(!regex.test(inputElementValue)){
                    spanElementObject.appendChild(document.createTextNode(helpMessage));
                    return false;
                }else{
                    return true;    
                }
            }
            function isTheValueValid(inputElementObject, spanElementObject){
                return editSpanElementText(
                                    /^[\u0041-\u005A\u0061-\u007A\.\' \-]{2,15}\s?[\u0041-\u005A\u0061-\u007A\.\' \-]{0,15}\s?[\u0041-\u005A\u0061-\u007A\.\' \-]{2,15}$/, 
                                    inputElementObject.value, 
                                    spanElementObject, 
                                    'Please enter a valid name.');      
            }
        </script>
```

---

For the first try, on losing focus on input element, error message, `Please enter a valid name.` gets rendered on giving **wrong** input value.

For the second try, on losing focus on input element, error message `Please enter a valid name.` does not get removed on giving **correct** input value.

On debugging `forEach` does not delete the `#text` childnode.

Why `delete` does not delete the properties?

Comment: http://perfectionkills.com/understanding-delete/

Comment: You are looking for https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ChildNode/remove or even simpler https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/removeChild

Comment: @Bergi Now `removeChild` is not what am looking for. I am trying to understand why `delete` does not work. Am not comfortable for this question being duplicate. am reading your reference on `delete`. it is a very long article

Comment: `delete` does not work because it is just wrong, on so many levels. Read the article I linked in my first comment.

Comment: @Bergi  To understand, why `delete` does not work? am reading that article. I may require 2-3 hours for this. It is a very long article. Obviously, you have made my job more difficult. I used `removeChild` many times before

Comment: OK, I'll write up an answer, but you still should read the article

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why does `delete` not remove the child elements?

You've made two big mistakes here:

- Applying `delete` on a variable. The [`delete` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete) deletes properties from objects, you didn't give it one (and naming that variable "property" doesn't change anything). Read http://perfectionkills.com/understanding-delete/.
- Expecting that deleting properties from a `NodeList` would change the DOM. Apart from them probably being non-deletable, that's not how the DOM works, only changing properties of the JS objects is not enough. You need to use the DOM API, in this case [`removeChild`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/removeChild). See also [Remove all child elements of a DOM node in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3955229/remove-all-child-elements-of-a-dom-node-in-javascript) for what you actually wanted to do.

Comment: OK. *either Activation object (for Function code), or Global object (for Global code), these properties are created with DontDelete attribute.* So, the `property` that was passed to the callback in the above code had `DontDelete` attribute? How do I verify that attribute value using code?

Comment: Yes, that's what it says. Variables cannot be deleted (except in some edge cases)

Comment: You can verify by trying to delete it and receiving `false` or an exception.