# How can i remove a div and its contents from the DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

im developing a web application and i am looking to return some error messages via ajax when there is error or success.

i have the ajax script working fine it returns and error or success however my issue is when returning the data i want it to remove the div #webapp_recovery from the dom all together not just hide it once its removed i want to show #webapp_notification

This is the form to submit a request via ajax

```
<div id='webapp_recovery' class='login-container'>
  <div class='page-content'>
    <div class='content'>
        <div class='panel panel-body login-form'>
            <div class='text-center'>
                <div class='icon-object border-slate-300 text-slate-300'><i class='icon-lock2'></i></div>
                <h5 class='content-group'>Reset Password  <small class='display-block'>Reset Your Account Password</small></h5>
            </div>
            <form method='POST' name='webapp_auth_recover'  id='webapp_auth_recover' class='webapp_auth_recover webapp_authentication_val3'>
                <div class='form-group has-feedback has-feedback-left'>
                    <input type='password' id='webapp_auth_password1' name='webapp_auth_password1' class='form-control required' placeholder='New Password' autocomplete='off'>
                        <div class='form-control-feedback'>
                            <i class='icon-lock2 text-muted'></i>
                        </div>
                </div>
                <div class='form-group has-feedback has-feedback-left'>
                    <input type='password'  name='webapp_auth_password2' class='form-control required' placeholder='Confirm Password' autocomplete='off'>
                        <div class='form-control-feedback'>
                            <i class='icon-lock2 text-muted'></i>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                <div class='form-group'>
                    <button type='submit' class='btn btn-primary btn-block'>Update Password <i class='icon-circle-right2 position-right'></i></button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

this is the error message i wish to show

```
<div id='webapp_notification' class='login-container'>
<div class='page-content'>
    <div class='content'>
        <div class='panel panel-body login-reset'>
            <div class='text-center'>
                <div class='icon-object border-slate-300 text-slate-300'><i class='icon-warning22'></i></div>
                <h5 class='content-group'>Systems Error <small class='display-block'>Erros have been found</small></h5>
            </div>
            <div class='form-control-static'>
                <p>errors have been detected</p>
            </div>
        </div>                  
    </div>
</div>
```

i have tried the following but they dont seem to work

```
$("#webapp_recovery").hide(); //as it says hides the div
$("#webapp_recovery").remove(); //this only removes the single div not all inside
```

is this at all possible or is there another method for returning a new div for message and removing the old

Comment: Please elaborate on what "they dont seem to work" means? How do you call that code? Have you checked the console for errors?

Comment: Can you create a jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net to demonstrate ?

Comment: after trying some of the solutions below it seems to work and remove everything from inside them dom.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove all child elements of a DOM node in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3955229/remove-all-child-elements-of-a-dom-node-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('#webapp_recovery').remove();
```

Will remove the div and all its children however if you want to remove all elements yourself you can do this:

```
$('#webapp_recovery *').remove();
$('#webapp_recovery').remove()
```

Comment: are there pros or cons to hiding vs removing

Answer (score 2):

Try jquery replaceWith function

Here's a sample fiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/gianoneil/zofm4qx6/

say, your error div is hidden on page load, then
here's how it's gonna look like

```
  $('#webapp_recovery').replaceWith(
    $('#webapp_notification').show()
  );
```

try playing with jQuery replaceWith, show, & hide functions, and you should be able to accomplish your mission :) have fun

Comment: Sir, I think `.show()` will be more efficient than using `.css('display','block')`.

Comment: Yes, I actually forgot to use that, thanks for reminding me

Answer (score 1):

Remove should delete the element as well as contents. This is from the JQ api: "Use .remove() when you want to remove the element itself, as well as everything inside it.".

So I would use the following if your webapp_notification div already exists in the DOM:

```
$("#webapp_recovery").remove();
$("#webapp_notification").show(); //hide this initially.
```

Otherwise, if you are removing the old and adding the new, you could use something like:

```
$("#webapp_recovery").after($("#webapp_notification")).remove();
```

Answer (score 1):

Using

```
$("#webapp_recovery").children().hide();
$("#webapp_recovery").hide();
```

will hide the div and the elements inside it.

Answer (score 0):

This method doesn't use jQuery, if the parent element id is `webapp_recovery`:

```
var tmp=document.getElementById("webapp_recovery");
tmp.parentNode.removeChild(tmp);
```