# How to dynamically remove content from a div after it has been appended with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

How can I remove any of the items that were added previously using Javascript append? I get the 'Node was not found' error.

See my plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/CWOxWh3SL5RBFmgJIiwS

html:

```
    <div style="display:none">    
    <div id="iteminitial">      
    <div class="row" style="padding: 0.5em 0 0.5em 0.5em">
          <div class="col-sm-4" >
               <input class="form-control" type="text" name="number[]">
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-4" >
               <input class="form-control" type="text" name="period[]">                   
          </div>  
          <div class="col-sm-4" >
               <input class="btn btn-default" type="button" value="Remove item" onClick="removeitem();">                   
          </div>              
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>


    <div id="item">     

    </div>


    <div class="row" style="padding: 0.5em 0 0.5em 0.5em">                  
          <input class="btn btn-default" type="button" value="Add another item" onClick="additem();">
    </div>
```

js:

```
function additem(){

      var newitem          = document.getElementById('item');
      var initialitem_clone      = document.getElementById('iteminitial').cloneNode(true);

      newitem.appendChild(initialitem_clone);
} 

function removeitem(){

      var olditem          = document.getElementById('item');
      olditem.removeChild(olditem); 
}
```

Comment: How is oldItem a child of itself?

Comment: IF you look at the html, those items that are added to not have an id.  They look like '<input class="form-control" name="period[]" type="text">'.  You chould give the node a unique and id before appending it, then remove like document.getElementById('item4') or whatever

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use [element.remove()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ChildNode/remove). Also, you should create unique **id** attribute values for the cloned items. See the example below:

```js
var itemCount = 1;
    function additem(){
          var newitem          = document.getElementById('item');
          var initialitem_clone      = document.getElementById('iteminitial').cloneNode(true);
          //make the id value unique
          initialitem_clone.id = 'item_'+itemCount++;
          newitem.appendChild(initialitem_clone);
    } 
    
    function removeitem(item){
          //item corresponds to the link that was clicked
          item.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.remove(); 
    }
```

```html
 <div style="display:none">    
    <div id="iteminitial">      
    <div class="row" style="padding: 0.5em 0 0.5em 0.5em">
          <div class="col-sm-4" >
               <input class="form-control" type="text" name="number[]">
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-4" >
               <input class="form-control" type="text" name="period[]">                   
          </div>  
          <div class="col-sm-4" >
<!-- pass this to the removeitem function -->
               <input class="btn btn-default" type="button" value="Remove item" onClick="removeitem(this);">                   
          </div>              
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>


    <div id="item">     

    </div>


    <div class="row" style="padding: 0.5em 0 0.5em 0.5em">                  
          <input class="btn btn-default" type="button" value="Add another item" onClick="additem();">
    </div>
```

Comment: Ok, I was missing lots of details to make it work. That is excellent. Thanks so much, I modified my plunker

Answer (score 0):

Since you already have a reference to the parent object, you can follow up this SO post to see how to remove all the children.

[Remove all child elements of a DOM node in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3955229/remove-all-child-elements-of-a-dom-node-in-javascript)

If you want to remove only particular children of that node, you will have to remember references to them somewhere.