# How append in jquery in for loop with setInterval without getting an infinite loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am making a listing system that updates checking new data from a json file every **3 seconds** by appending the **response.list[i].firstname** to document.getElementById("list"). but i am getting unlimited loop.

**output:**
name1
name2
name1
name2
name1
name2
(to infinity..)

```
<script>
list();
setInterval(list, 3000);
function list() {
$.getJSON('list.php',function(response){
        for(var i = 0; i < response.list_count; i++){
        var newElement = document.createElement('div');
        newElement.innerHTML = response.list[i].firstname;
        document.getElementById("list").appendChild(newElement);
        }
    document.getElementById("list_count").innerHTML = "" +  response.list_count; + ""; 
});
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because every 3 seconds you read JSON file and append it to the already rendered (with all the data appended in previous runs) list with

```
document.getElementById("list").appendChild(newElement);
```

If you want to show only the content of the file once, then you should clean the target list div with one of the methods described in here:
[Remove all child elements of a DOM node in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3955229/remove-all-child-elements-of-a-dom-node-in-javascript)

for example:
    $('#list').empty();

Alternatively, you need to keep track of what you have already added to the list, and append only the new entries, but that might be a bit more tricky, if there is no unique identifiers in the json data that you render.

So, with the first solutioin it will be something like:

```
list();
setInterval(list, 3000);
function list() {
$.getJSON('list.php',function(response){
        $('#list').empty();
        for(var i = 0; i < response.list_count; i++){
        var newElement = document.createElement('div');
        newElement.innerHTML = response.list[i].firstname;
        document.getElementById("list").appendChild(newElement);
        }
    document.getElementById("list_count").innerHTML = "" +  response.list_count; + ""; 
});
};
```

Comment: Thank you for your answering. Infinite loop is gone. :)

Answer (score 0):

I have shared how to get length of JSON response.

```
var obj = JSON.parse(response);

var limit=Object.keys(obj).length;

for( var i = 0; i < limit; i++ ) {

}
```

I am not sure about response.**list_count** you are using. Is that a finite number?

Comment: list_count is the count of rows in the database. if the i have 2 names in the database like (name1, name2) list_count = 2;