# Remove all elements inside div

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do I remove all the contents inside my mainDiv?

```
<div id='mainDiv'>
   <fieldset>
       <div>
           <input type='text'>
           <select></select>
       </div>
   </fieldset>
</div>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove all child elements of a DOM node in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3955229/remove-all-child-elements-of-a-dom-node-in-javascript)

Comment: You can use 1 line code: 

if using pure javascript 

try:`document.getElementById('mainDiv').innerHTML = '';`


if using jQuery try: `$('#mainDiv').html('');`

Answer (score 0):

```
document.querySelector('#mainDiv').innerHTML = '';
```