# How to delete all Child Elements from a div element using JS

Tags: javascript

Hey guys i am learning JS, the thing is i made a simple application which display the multiplication table of the input number. The problem is that when i enter a number again the it will print below the previous multiplication table so i want to delete all the child element of div tag when i enter a number again

```
function print() {
    var box = document.getElementById("table");

    for(let i=1 ; i<=10 ; i++) {
        var t = document.getElementById("tabInput").value;
        var t_Element = document.createElement("p");
        var t_line = document.createTextNode(t + " x " + i + " = " + t*i);
        t_Element.appendChild(t_line);
        box.appendChild(t_Element);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show us what you've tried? so that we can help you better

Comment: Need an identifier for the div.

Comment: "Table" is the identifier of div

Comment: This is exactly the same question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3955229/remove-all-child-elements-of-a-dom-node-in-javascript

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you need to clear ALL elements, then there is no need to iterate through them.

You can just clear the `innerHTML` of the `div` like so:

```
document.getElementById('yourdivid').innerHTML = '';
```

And then you can proceed with the rest of your code that creates the new elements

Comment: This approach does not remove the event handlers of the removed child nodes, potentially leading to memory leak.

Comment: @danefondo could you kindly expand? I understand the first part of your comment but I don't know enough to understand how that could create a memory leak thank you.

Answer (score 3):

If you clear the html with `innerHTML = ''`, you still are going to have those previous html nodes loaded. For now the best way to do it is to iterate and destroy each node with

```js
while (box.hasChildElements()) {
  box.removeChild(box.lastChild)
}
```

Comment: You have an extra closing paren. Should be box.removeChild(box.lastChild);

Comment: hasChildElements? Maybe you mean "hasChildNodes" (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/hasChildNodes)

Answer (score 0):

if you have a lot of elements and need a really fast way, you can clone the node with false deep option then replace it.

```
let parentNode = document.querySelector("#parentNode"),
   replacedNode = document.querySelector("#replacedNode"),
   newNode = replacedNode.cloneNode(false);
parentNode.replaceChild(newNode, replacedNode)
```