# Is there a way so that elements which are getting added inside javascript function on the click of array of elements should be added only once?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Pre-Requisite: `allPanelElems1[j]` has elements such as `t1`, `t2`, `t3` etc. which are `div` elements.

I am calling the javascript function `handlePanelClick1` on array of elements. Inside the function I am adding up some other element i.e `apiinfo`. Now this function is called for each of element inside array `allPanelElems1[j]`. When a user clicks on any element of `allPanelElems1[j]` (let's say `t1`), then inside function element `apiinfo` is added successfully but when user clicks on the same element (`t1`) again then the element `apiinfo` is added again.

Is there a way, so that when user click on any element for the first time the `apiinfo` element should be added. But if the user calls the element again then `apiinfo` should not be added. Similarly for other elements `t2`, `t3` etc ?

```js
var allPanelElems1 = accordionElem.querySelectorAll(".panel1");
for (var j = 0, len1 = allPanelElems1.length; j < len1; j++) {
  allPanelElems1[j].addEventListener("click", handlePanelClick1);
}

function handlePanelClick1(event) {
  if (event.currentTarget.getAttribute('class').indexOf('active') >= 0) {
    event.currentTarget.classList.remove("active");
  } else {
    prod1 = {
      "Testcase": [{
          "apiName": " demoAPIname1",
          "request": "req",
          "response": " res"
        },
        {
          "apiName": " demoAPI name2",
          "request": " req",
          "response": "res"
        }

      ]
    };

    var projectBody1 = document.createElement("div");
    for (var propt1 in prod1) {
      var projectBody2 = document.createElement("div");
      var project1 = prod1[propt1];

      for (var i in project1) {
        var temp = document.createElement("div");
        var apiname = project1[i].apiName;
        var request1 = project1[i].request;
        var response1 = project1[i].response;

        var t1 = document.createElement("div");
        var r1 = document.createElement("div");
        var t2 = document.createElement("div");
        var r2 = document.createElement("div");
        r1.innerHTML = request1;
        r2.innerHTML = response1;
        t1.appendChild(createPanel("request", r1, "apidata"));
        t2.appendChild(createPanel("response", r2, "apidata"));

        temp.appendChild(t1);
        temp.appendChild(t2);

        projectBody2.appendChild(createPanel(apiname, temp, "apipanel"));
      }

    }
    projectBody1.appendChild(createPanel("apiinfo", projectBody2, "apititle"));

    var accordion4 = event.currentTarget; //THIS LINE I AM ASSIGNING MY current element
    accordion4.appendChild(projectBody1);

    var allPanelElems4 = accordion4.querySelectorAll(".panel");
    for (var i = 0, len = allPanelElems4.length; i < len; i++) {
      allPanelElems4[i].addEventListener("click", handlePanelClick);
    }
    event.currentTarget.classList.add("active");
  }

  event.stopPropagation();
}
```

Comment: Please post a working version of the code, including markup and javascript, that people here can run, debug and then help you with.

Comment: Hi Please find jsfiddle link for the same : https://jsfiddle.net/swati004/x4Lmzack/1/

Comment: In this while clicking any testcase lets say Testcase1 inside demoname3, it adds an element apiinfo but if you double click on it then again apiinfo is getting added. i just want to add element apiinfo for each testcase only once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I mean this sounds pretty stupid but couldn't you just clear the element's child/s before adding the new one? So It would only ever exist once?

```
element.innerHTML = "";
...
...
element.appendChild(child);
```

In case speed matters: [Children removal](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3955238/103156) ... sounds bad xD

Or you could check if the child count is more than 1

```
if(div.childNodes.length > 1) return
```

Check a specific ID

```
let children = Array.from(div.childNodes);
for(let i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
    if(children[i].id == "onlyOnce") return;
}
// Append child then as following: 
let childElement = document.createElement("div");
childElement.id = "onlyOnce";
div.appendChild(childElement);
```

**EDIT:**

Greeting Elias :D

Comment: No problem :) In case it really worked, you could accept it as the answer =)