# HTML Emptying div contents

Tags: javascript, html, dom

To empty a `div`s contents, consider for example a `graph_container` div containing `svg` element which in turn contains thousands of elements, we can do

```
graph_container.innerHTML = ''
```

or a more efficient way to remove elements is

```
while (graph_container.firstChild)
    graph_container.removeChild(graph_container.firstChild);
```

Benchmarks can be found at https://jsperf.com/innerhtml-vs-removechild

But it's hard to perceive why chucking all sub-elements without even looking at them is not fast or why removing all subelements elementwise is better for DOM.

**Why can't the DOM remove links to the subtree and destroy the subtree altogether, which I think should be efficient than the while loop which can neither be parallized nor be executed in one shot?**

EDIT: The [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3955229/remove-all-child-elements-of-a-dom-node-in-javascript) mentioned in the comments, is about how to remove them and the answer has both the methods stated in the question. But it does *not* tell why one is better than the other and does not answer the question above.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove all child elements of a DOM node in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3955229/remove-all-child-elements-of-a-dom-node-in-javascript)

Comment: @MatthewG The answers from that question are part of this question; I don't see how this can be a duplicate... It's not necessarily a good question (asking random people on the internet why a browser does something is asking for supposition), but I don't think it's a duplicate of that question.

Comment: and what is the question?