# [Vue][SSR] Suppress hydration mismatch warning

Tags: vue.js, server-side-rendering

I'm rendering a Vue component to HTML and it is expected that the DOM rendering/hydration doesn't completely match the HTML rendered version.

How can I supress the hydration mismatch warning?

In React there is https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#suppresshydrationwarning ([Is there any way to avoid "Text content did not match" warning in SSR with React?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53959948/is-there-any-way-to-avoid-text-content-did-not-match-warning-in-ssr-with-react)) — is there a Vue counterpart to this?

(Context: I'm the author of the new frontend framework [Vike](https://vike.dev) and some of my users need that.)

Comment: All the warnings/errors seem to come from this file https://github.com/vuejs/vue-next/blob/58b1fa5ed15edc7264785cd722282a011ea3042c/packages/runtime-core/src/hydration.ts with no options to supress the warnings.

Comment: Not sure if it's somehow helpful but you could maybe look at this question (related to Nuxt): https://stackoverflow.com/q/47862591/8816585 To not find a solution to suppress the actual warning but to spot and avoid it.

Comment: On top of that, it seems (from the code) those warnings are only raised in DEV env...

Comment: This happen just in production? Where do you deploy that?

Comment: This one is not related to production-only and can usually be simply reproduced by building locally (if no error during dev). @PeterDev

Answer (score 1):

I wish that I can help by commenting on your post instead of posting answers. But you can give this a try:

There is no direct equivalent to React's react-dom/suppressHydrationWarning in Vue, but you can suppress the warning message in a few ways:

By setting the warning option to false in the Vue component:

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <p v-warning="false">This will not generate a warning</p>
  </div>
</template>
```

By setting the global Vue.config. warning option to false :

```
Vue.config.warning = false
```

By setting the environment variable VUE_WARNING_DISABLE to true :

```js
export VUE_WARNING_DISABLE = true
```

Or by using the vue-cli-plugin-suppress-warnings plugin.

Comment: `v-warning` does not seem to be a valid directive, getting error `[Vue warn]: Failed to resolve directive: warning`

Comment: @IvanLim which version of Nuxt? I suggest a new question with a [repro].

Comment: @kissu Nuxt 3.6.5. I did not spend time resolving it as I changed the logic to remove the hydration warning instead (by moving the content change code to onMounted).

I did do a quick search on Google using keywords 'nuxt v-warning' and did not find any Nuxt documentation. Evidence that `v-warning` is not built-in to Nuxt?

Comment: @IvanLim `v-warning` is either coming from Vuetify or a custom directive yes, nothing related to Nuxt directly. Hence why the error is also happening, because it is probably external and does not support SSR. The answer provide above is more of pseudo-code hard way of suppressing it, not really a good approach overall as of how to solve a given problem (the miss match will still happen, which is quite a bad thing).

Comment: Using vue/ssr directly, also seeing the same error. This is a custom directive defined outside vanilla vue. Error: `[Vue warn]: Failed to resolve directive: warning`

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there is a Vue counterpart to `suppressHydrationWarning` but one thing you may try is to manually remove the DOM content before you hydrate.

```js
const rootId = 'app'
const root = document.getElementById(vueRootId)
root.innerHTML = ''
// Your hydration code
// ...
```

See [Remove all child elements of a DOM node in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3955229/remove-all-child-elements-of-a-dom-node-in-javascript) for alternative ways to remove the childs of a DOM element.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into something similar, this is what worked for my use-case. I'd love to know if anyone has a better approach.

---

If you have a component that you'd like to ignore on the server side, you could use the following approach.

First create a `<ClientOnly>` component similar to what [vitepress](https://github.com/vuejs/vitepress/blob/49ddb1f120f1c66c6c8d1a7e388e2f49bdf1c552/src/client/app/components/ClientOnly.ts) has.

```
import { ref, onMounted, defineComponent } from 'vue'

const ClientOnly = defineComponent({
  setup(_, { slots }) {
    const show = ref(false)
    onMounted(() => {
      show.value = true
    })
    return () => (show.value && slots.default ? slots.default() : null)
  }
})

export {
  ClientOnly,
}
```

Using this in your template will stop the Hydration warning but it won't stop the server side bundle from including the component.

You can add a `v-if` using the env value from `!import.meta.env.SSR`.

Here is a modified `template-ssr-vue` example from vite. You can view the [original](https://github.com/bluwy/create-vite-extra/blob/0fa6c0716bea13c5522ab141dd56dea7c8e25d09/template-ssr-vue/src/components/HelloWorld.vue) here.

```
<script setup lang="ts">
import { ref } from 'vue'
import { ClientOnly } from './ClientOnly'

defineProps<{ msg: string }>()

const count = ref(0)
const treeShakeServerSide = !import.meta.env.SSR;
</script>

<template>
  <h1>{{ msg }}</h1>

  <div class="card">
    <button type="button" @click="count++">count is {{ count }}</button>
    <p>
      Edit
      <code>components/HelloWorld.vue</code> to test HMR
    </p>
  </div>


  <!-- Client only without Hydration warnings -->

  <ClientOnly>
    <div>This will be rendered on client side only</div>

    <div v-if="treeShakeServerSide">This won't be included in the /dist/server/entry-server.js file.</div>
  </ClientOnly>


  <p>
    Check out
    <a href="https://vuejs.org/guide/quick-start.html#local" target="_blank"
      >create-vue</a
    >, the official Vue + Vite starter
  </p>
  <p>
    Install
    <a href="https://github.com/johnsoncodehk/volar" target="_blank">Volar</a>
    in your IDE for a better DX
  </p>
  <p class="read-the-docs">Click on the Vite and Vue logos to learn more</p>
</template>

<style scoped>
.read-the-docs {
  color: #888;
}
</style>
```

Comment: `client-only` is native to Nuxt already.