# Vite, Vue3, Koa SSR error `Hydration completed but contains mismatches`

Tags: vuejs3, vite, server-side-rendering, koa, hydration

I'm currently working on converting an existing Vue 3 front-end project into an SSR (Server-Side Rendering) project using `Vite`, `Vue 3`, `Pinia`, `vue-i18n` and `Koa`.
However, I've run into an issue. My repository is available.

[kun-galgame-vue](https://github.com/KUN1007/kun-galgame-vue)

The key code is: `index.html`, `server-dev.ts`, `server-prod.ts`, `entry-client.ts`, `entry-server.ts`, `vite.config.ts`

A similar issue is https://github.com/vitejs/vite/issues/7900

I've searched for some related articles and discussions, but due to the console error showing only a one-liner error message without specifying which component is causing the issue, I can't pinpoint the exact reason for the error.

[[Vue][SSR] Suppress hydration mismatch warning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68438016/vuessr-suppress-hydration-mismatch-warning)

When run `pnpm dev` ("dev": "ts-node-esm server-dev.ts"), an error occurred

The console error is

> entry-client.ts:19 [Vue warn]: Hydration node mismatch:
>
> - Client vnode: Symbol(v-fgt)
> - Server rendered DOM: 
>   at 
>   warn2 @ runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:41
>   handleMismatch @ runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:4869
>   onMismatch @ runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:4538
>   hydrateNode @ runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:4615
>   hydrateSubTree @ runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:5723
>   componentUpdateFn @ runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:5743
>   run @ reactivity.esm-bundler.js:178
>   instance.update @ runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:5862
>   setupRenderEffect @ runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:5870
>   mountComponent @ runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:5660
>   hydrateNode @ runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:4651
>   hydrate2 @ runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:4529
>   mount @ runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:3830
>   app.mount @ runtime-dom.esm-bundler.js:1468
>   (anonymous) @ entry-client.ts:19
>   Promise.then (async)
>   (anonymous) @ entry-client.ts:18

> entry-client.ts:19 Hydration completed but contains mismatches.

It seems that SSR didn't take effect for the rendered HTML
[console error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r7klA.png)

The project I referenced is [koa2-ssr-vite-vue3-ts-pinia](https://github.com/jeddygong/vite-templates/tree/master/koa2-ssr-vite-vue3-ts-pinia). From this project, it can be seen that `<!--ssr-outlet-->` is correctly replaced with the rendered HTML. However, in my project, `<!--ssr-outlet-->` remains unchanged and is not replaced.

Here are some other related SSR projects where you can see the rendered pages in the browser preview, but my page is blank:

> https://github.com/dmoosocool/vite-koa-ssr

I use Vue 3's Teleport in the code, which seems to cause hydration mismatches

> https://vuejs.org/guide/scaling-up/ssr.html#teleports

```js
<template>
  <Teleport to="body" :disabled="showAlert">
    <Transition name="alert">
      <div v-if="showAlert" class="mask">
        ...
      </div>
    </Transition>
  </Teleport>
</template>
```

I also use a few `native DOM operations` and the browser's `fetch API` to fetch backend data:

```js
    // Set the theme, there are only two modes
    // , light and dark, with light represented as ''
    setKUNGalgameTheme(theme: '' | 'dark') {
      this.showKUNGalgameMode = theme
      document.documentElement.className = theme
    },
```

```js
// Fetch request function
const kunFetchRequest = async <T>(
  url: string,
  options: FetchOptions
): Promise<T> => {
  const baseUrl = import.meta.env.VITE_API_BASE_URL
  const fullUrl = `${baseUrl}${url}`

  // Add the token to the request headers
  const headers = {
    ...options.headers,
    Authorization: `Bearer ${useKUNGalgameUserStore().getToken()}`,
  }

  const response = await fetch(fullUrl, { ...options, headers })

  // If not 20X, then throw an error
  if (!successResponseArray.includes(response.status)) {
    // Handle errors, such as token expiration
    await onRequestError(response)
    throw new Error('KUNGalgame Fetch Error occurred, but no problem')
  }

  const data: T = await response.json()
  return data
}
```