# reset contents in the container while select is on change

Tags: javascript, html, css

I created this JavaScript code which detects the value (number) of `select` tags and creates `div` contents based on that value and appends them into the container, but when I change the value again it keeps going, it doesn't reset.

**The code is the following:**

```js
const select = document.getElementsByTagName('select')[0];
const container = document.getElementById('container');
select.onchange = () => {
  for (let i = 0; i < Number(select.value); i++) {
    let content = document.createElement('div');
    content.classList.add('content');
    container.appendChild(content);
  }
}
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  height: 100vh;
}

.app {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 12% 88%;
  background: #5F9EA0;
}

select {
  width: 60px;
  height: 40px;
  background: red;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 24px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  outline: none;
}

#container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: darkcyan;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
}

.content {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  background: darkgreen;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="app">
  <select>
    <option>0</option>
    <option>3</option>
    <option>6</option>
    <option>9</option>
  </select>
  <div id="container"></div>
</div>
```

How can I reset the contents before adding the other contents?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove all child elements of a DOM node in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3955229/remove-all-child-elements-of-a-dom-node-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reset container by setting its innerHTML to empty string.

```js
const select = document.getElementsByTagName('select')[0];
const container = document.getElementById('container');
select.onchange = () => {
  // reset
  container.innerHTML = "";

  for (let i = 0; i < Number(select.value); i++) {
    let content = document.createElement('div');
    content.classList.add('content');
    container.appendChild(content);
  }
}
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  height: 100vh;
}

.app {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 12% 88%;
  background: #5F9EA0;
}

select {
  width: 60px;
  height: 40px;
  background: red;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 24px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  outline: none;
}

#container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: darkcyan;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
}

.content {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  background: darkgreen;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="app">
  <select>
    <option>0</option>
    <option>3</option>
    <option>6</option>
    <option>9</option>
  </select>
  <div id="container"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: This might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3955229/remove-all-child-elements-of-a-dom-node-in-javascript

Comment: Sorry @kudlas i no mean to disrespect your answer, just when i was posting my answer your answer was not loaded. if you want me to delte my answer, i will

Answer (score 2):

you see on change iam removing everything inside container then goes your logic

```
const select = document.getElementsByTagName('select')[0];
            const container = document.getElementById('container');
            select.onchange = () => {
                container.innerHTML = "";
                for (let i = 0; i < Number(select.value); i++) {
                    let content = document.createElement('div');
                    content.classList.add('content'); container.appendChild(content);
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:
check if the current select.value is less or equal the original squares if true, you remove all of them and then add the new squares according to the number selected

```
    const addSquares = select => {
  for (let i = 0; i < Number(select.value); i++) {
    let content = document.createElement("div")
    content.classList.add("content")
    container.appendChild(content)
  }
}
const select = document.getElementsByTagName("select")[0]
const container = document.getElementById("container")
select.onchange = () => {
  const squares = document.querySelectorAll(".content")
  const squareArr = Array.from(squares)
  const { value } = select
  if (value <= squareArr.length) {
    squareArr.forEach(function (node) {
      node.parentNode.removeChild(node)
    })
  }
  addSquares(select)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this is the most convenient way.
Each time you click the button, you need to clear the previous time

```
const select = document.getElementsByTagName('select')[0];
    const container = document.getElementById('container');
    select.onchange = () => {
        container.innerHTML = '';
        for (let i = 0; i < Number(select.value); i++) {
            let content = document.createElement('div');
            content.classList.add('content');
            container.appendChild(content);
        }
    }
```