# Changing a HTML element dynamically

Tags: javascript, html

I have a side drawer where I'm showing the current cart products selected by the user. Initially, I have a `<p>` tag saying the cart is empty. However, I want to remove it if the cart has items inside. I'm using an OOP approach to design this page. See below the class I'm working with.

I tried to use an if statement to condition the `<p>` tag but this seems the wrong approach. Anyone has a better way to do this. See screenshot of the cart in the UI and code below:

[image: Without cart item]

[image: with item]

```
class SideCartDrawer {
    cartProducts = [];

    constructor() {
        this.productInCartEl = document.getElementById('item-cart-template');
    }

    addToCart(product) {
        const updatedProducts = [...this.cartProducts];
        updatedProducts.push(product);
        this.cartProducts = updatedProducts;
        this.renderCart();
    }

    renderCart() {
        const cartListHook = document.getElementById('cart-items-list');
        let cartEl = null;
        if (this.cartProducts.length === 0) {
            cartEl = '<h2>You Cart is Empty</h2>';
        } else {
            const productInCartElTemplate = document.importNode(
                this.productInCartEl.content,
                true
            );
            cartEl = productInCartElTemplate.querySelector('.cart-item');
            for (let productInCart of this.cartProducts) {
                cartEl.querySelector('h3').textContent = productInCart.productName;
                cartEl.querySelector('p').textContent = `£ ${productInCart.price}`;
                cartEl.querySelector('span').textContent = 1;
            }
        }
        cartListHook.append(cartEl);
    }
}
```

By the way, the `<p>` should reappear if the cart is back to empty :) !

Comment: You can try clearing all nodes using remove and adding the nodes based on the condition of cart empty or not

Comment: to get help, you should add html and javascript that is called on cart change.

Answer (score 1):

With how your code is setup, you would want to reset the list on each render. You would do this by totally clearing out `#cart-items-list`. Here is a deletion method from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3955229/remove-all-child-elements-of-a-dom-node-in-javascript)

```
while (cartListHook.firstChild) {
  cartListHook.removeChild(cartListHook.lastChild);
}
```

But you could use any method to delete the children of an HTML Node. To reiterate, you would put this *right after* getting the element by its id.

- P.S. You probably want to put more code into your for loop, because it seems like it will only create cart-item element even if there are multiple items in `this.cartProducts`.