# Remove child div from parent div

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to remove each child div inside a parent div using for loop something like this:

```js
for (var x = 0; x < parent.length; x++) {
  parent[x].remove();
}
```

Here's my code for reference:

```js
var remove5 = document.getElementById('social');
```

```html
<div class="col-md-4" id="col-md-4" id="social">
  <div class="footer-col" id="footer-col">
    <h4>Social Media</h4>
    <span class="fa-stack">
      <a href="#your-link">
        <i class="fas fa-circle fa-stack-2x"></i>
        <i class="fab fa-facebook-f fa-stack-1x"></i>
      </a>
    </span>
    <span class="fa-stack">
      <a href="#your-link">
        <i class="fas fa-circle fa-stack-2x"></i>
        <i class="fab fa-twitter fa-stack-1x"></i>
      </a>
    </span>
    <span class="fa-stack">
      <a href="#your-link">
        <i class="fas fa-circle fa-stack-2x"></i>
        <i class="fab fa-google-plus-g fa-stack-1x"></i>
      </a>
    </span>
    <span class="fa-stack">
      <a href="#your-link">
        <i class="fas fa-circle fa-stack-2x"></i>
        <i class="fab fa-instagram fa-stack-1x"></i>
      </a>
    </span>
    <span class="fa-stack">
      <a href="#your-link">
        <i class="fas fa-circle fa-stack-2x"></i>
        <i class="fab fa-linkedin-in fa-stack-1x"></i>
      </a>
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

so, I want to remove all divs inside the first di with the Id `social`

Comment: What's the question? Have you tried this? How is it not working?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `for (var x = 0; x < children.length; x++)`?

Comment: How do you set the variable `parent`?

Comment: Your code should work if you do `parent = remove5.querySelectorAll("div");`

Comment: the parent div its id = social, I want to delete all the divs inside it @Barmar

Comment: `while (remove5.firstChild) {
        remove5.removeChild(remove5.firstChild);
    }`

Comment: @OmarShuaili What problem are you having? If you set `parent` correctly, your code should work.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove all child elements of a DOM node in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3955229/remove-all-child-elements-of-a-dom-node-in-javascript)

Comment: All `divs` in side ? or just one layer deep? Do you want to just remove the `div` tag or do you want to remove the div and it's contents.

Comment: all `divs` inside @JonP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to remove all child `div` use `querySelectorAll()`.

You also have 2 id attributes in your parent `div` you can only have one.

```js
let childDivs = document.querySelectorAll("#social > div");
for(var i = 0; i < childDivs.length; i++){
  childDivs[i].remove();
}
```

```html
<div class="col-md-4" id="social">
  <div class="footer-col" id="footer-col">
    <h4>Social Media</h4>
    <span class="fa-stack">
                            <a href="#your-link">
                                <i class="fas fa-circle fa-stack-2x"></i>
                                <i class="fab fa-facebook-f fa-stack-1x"></i>
                            </a>
                        </span>
    <span class="fa-stack">
                            <a href="#your-link">
                                <i class="fas fa-circle fa-stack-2x"></i>
                                <i class="fab fa-twitter fa-stack-1x"></i>
                            </a>
                        </span>
    <span class="fa-stack">
                            <a href="#your-link">
                                <i class="fas fa-circle fa-stack-2x"></i>
                                <i class="fab fa-google-plus-g fa-stack-1x"></i>
                            </a>
                        </span>
    <span class="fa-stack">
                            <a href="#your-link">
                                <i class="fas fa-circle fa-stack-2x"></i>
                                <i class="fab fa-instagram fa-stack-1x"></i>
                            </a>
                        </span>
    <span class="fa-stack">
                            <a href="#your-link">
                                <i class="fas fa-circle fa-stack-2x"></i>
                                <i class="fab fa-linkedin-in fa-stack-1x"></i>
                            </a>
                        </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Hi Omar,**

There is no need to use the loop in this case to clear your parent's div content, we can use the .empty() method using the **[jQuery Framework](https://jquery.com/)** for this in order to fulfill this need on the parent. Please be aware that you need to correct a typo on your parent div, you have declared the id attribute twice and only one can be set and will take priority.

With that being said, please go ahead and run this snippet of code, and whatever it is inside the social div will be cleared after you hit the button below the paragraph.

I certainly hope this helps. Cheers, mate!

```js
$("button").click(function(){
    $("#social").empty();
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head></head>
   <body>
      <div class="col-md-4" id="social">
         <div class="footer-col" id="footer-col">
            <h4>Social Media</h4>
            <p>This text and the title above will be erased when you click the button below.</p>
            <span class="fa-stack">
            <a href="#your-link">
            <i class="fas fa-circle fa-stack-2x"></i>
            <i class="fab fa-facebook-f fa-stack-1x"></i>
            </a>
            </span>
            <span class="fa-stack">
            <a href="#your-link">
            <i class="fas fa-circle fa-stack-2x"></i>
            <i class="fab fa-twitter fa-stack-1x"></i>
            </a>
            </span>
            <span class="fa-stack">
            <a href="#your-link">
            <i class="fas fa-circle fa-stack-2x"></i>
            <i class="fab fa-google-plus-g fa-stack-1x"></i>
            </a>
            </span>
            <span class="fa-stack">
            <a href="#your-link">
            <i class="fas fa-circle fa-stack-2x"></i>
            <i class="fab fa-instagram fa-stack-1x"></i>
            </a>
            </span>
            <span class="fa-stack">
            <a href="#your-link">
            <i class="fas fa-circle fa-stack-2x"></i>
            <i class="fab fa-linkedin-in fa-stack-1x"></i>
            </a>
            </span>
         </div>
      </div>
      <button>Empty Parent Div</button>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I did now, Jon! thanks for the tip! It seems to be that the person decided to give the answer I had to another post now. Good thing is that he finally found the help he needed.  :)