# clearing out all child elements from a div with PureScript

Tags: dom, purescript

There are lots of ways to [empty out a element of a DOM node with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3955229/remove-all-child-elements-of-a-dom-node-in-javascript). I would like to do this with PureScript (with the intent of replacing static content with a Halogen widget). It seems like among all the functions of [purescript-web-html](https://pursuit.purescript.org/packages/purescript-web-html/3.1.0) and [purescript-web-dom](https://pursuit.purescript.org/packages/purescript-web-dom/5.0.0) there ought to be an obvious way to to this, but the huge number of conflicting ways to describe a element are defeating me.

Is there a one or two line easy way to do what seems like an obvious operation before calling `runUI`?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is the best way to do this as it seems like there ought to be a nice functional way to `map` over an `HTMLCollection`, but at least it works:

```
import Data.Maybe (Maybe(..))
import Effect (Effect)
import Halogen.Aff as HA
import Halogen.VDom.Driver (runUI)
import Web.DOM.ParentNode
import Web.DOM.ChildNode (remove)
import Web.HTML.HTMLElement (HTMLElement, toParentNode)
import Web.DOM.Element (toChildNode)
import Effect.Class

selector :: QuerySelector
selector = QuerySelector "#halogen"

main :: Effect Unit
main = HA.runHalogenAff do
  body <- HA.awaitBody
  elem <- HA.selectElement selector
  case elem of
    Nothing -> runUI component unit body
    Just e -> do
       liftEffect $ clearChildren e
       runUI component unit e

clearChildren :: HTMLElement -> Effect Unit
clearChildren e = clearNextChild (toParentNode e)
  where
    clearNextChild :: ParentNode -> Effect Unit
    clearNextChild n = do
      last <- lastElementChild n
      case (last) of
        Nothing -> pure unit
        Just elem -> do 
          remove $ toChildNode elem
          clearNextChild n
```