# How can i remove previous searched items on next search

Tags: javascript, html, webapi, async.js

Getting images of all the movies starting with what user searched for just want to remove previous images on every next search how can i do that

```
<html lang="en">

<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport"     content="width=device-width, initial-  scale=1.0">
<title>TV Show Search</title>

<script     src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
<h1>TV Show Search</h1>
<form id="searchForm">
    <input type="text" placeholder="TV Show Title" name="query">
    <button>Search</button>
</form>
<script src="app.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

JavaScript Starts From Here

```
const form =   document.querySelector('#searchForm');
```

Added an eventlistener on form.

```
form.addEventListener('submit', async     function (e) {
e.preventDefault();
const searchTerm =     form.elements.query.value;
const config = { params: { q:    searchTerm } }
var res = await     axios.get(`http://api.tvmaze.com/search/shows`, config);
```

Getting results from an api

```
makeImages(res.data)
form.elements.query.value = '';

})



const makeImages = (shows) => {
for (let result of shows) {
    if (result.show.image) {
        const img =    document.createElement('IMG');
           img.src=result.show.image.medium;
        document.body.append(img)
    }
}
}
```

How can i remove previous images on next search

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way would probably be to remove all children, that is clear the element's `innerHTML`. To avoid messing up the rest of the page, consider moving your images to a separate `<div>`:

html:

```
<!-- ... -->
</form>
<div id="resultImages"></div>
<script src="app.js"></script>
<!-- ... -->
```

js:

```
const resultImagesDiv = document.getElementById('resultImages');

const makeImages = (shows) => {
  resultImagesDiv.innerHTML = ''; // Clear all previous images
  for (let result of shows) {
    if (result.show.image) {
      const img = document.createElement("img");
      img.src = result.show.image.medium;
      resultImagesDiv.appendChild(img);
    }
  }
};
```

For more details on how to remove all children of an Html element, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3955229/remove-all-child-elements-of-a-dom-node-in-javascript).

Answer (score 1):

resultImagesDiv.innerHtml = ''; - This is wrong. It should be innerText instead.

resultImagesDiv.innerText = '';

I'm assuming this is for a certain online bootcamp video on Udemy. If so, everyone that finds this should have the solution for the extra credit part he doesn't give the answer to.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const prevent = document.querySelector('#target')  const body = document.querySelectorAll('body')

prevent.addEventListener('click',function(e){
    e.preventDefault()
    getList()
    prevent.elements.query.value = ''
    clear()

   
    
})

const getList = async () =>{
    let searchInput = prevent.elements.query.value
    let param = {params:{q:searchInput}}
    try{
        const res = await axios.get(`https://api.tvmaze.com/search/shows`,param)
        for(let i of res.data ){
            if(i.show.image.medium){
                const img = document.createElement('img')
                img.src = i.show.image.medium
                document.body.append(img)
    
            }
        }
    }
    catch(e){
        console.log('Bad request',e)
    }
}

const clear = () =>{
    const img = document.querySelectorAll('img')
    for(let i of img){
        i.remove()
    }
}
document.querySelector('input').addEventListener('click', function(e){
e.stopPropagation();
})
```

```html
<html lang = "en">
<head>
  <meta charset ="UTF-8">
  <meta name = "viewport" content = "width=device-width, initial-scale = 1.0">
  <link rel = "stylesheets" href = "apps.css">
  <script src = "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Movies Search</h1>
    <form action ="https://www.google.com" id="target">
      <input type = "text" placeholder = "Search Movie" name = "query">
      <button>Search</button>
    </form>


</html>
```

```
const prevent = document.querySelector('#target') const body = document.querySelectorAll('body')

prevent.addEventListener('click',function(e){
    e.preventDefault()
    getList()
    prevent.elements.query.value = ''
    clear()

   
     })

const getList = async () =>{
    let searchInput = prevent.elements.query.value
    let param = {params:{q:searchInput}}
    try{
        const res = await axios.get(`https://api.tvmaze.com/search/shows`,param)
        for(let i of res.data ){
            if(i.show.image.medium){
                const img = document.createElement('img')
                img.src = i.show.image.medium
                document.body.append(img)
    
            }
        }
    }
    catch(e){
        console.log('Bad request',e)
    } }

const clear = () =>{
    const img = document.querySelectorAll('img')
    for(let i of img){
        i.remove()
    } } document.querySelector('input').addEventListener('click', function(e){ e.stopPropagation(); })

    enter code here   <html lang = "en"> <head>   <meta charset ="UTF-8">   <meta name = "viewport" content = "width=device-width, initial-scale = 1.0">   <link rel = "stylesheets" href = "apps.css">   <script src = "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>   </head>   <body>
    <h1>Movies Search</h1>
    <form action ="https://www.google.com" id="target">
      <input type = "text" placeholder = "Search Movie" name = "query">
      <button>Search</button>   </form> <div></div>

</html>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I added this to the makeImages function:

```
const existingImages = document.querySelectorAll('img');
    existingImages.forEach(img => img.remove());
```