# Need to refresh random image onclick

Tags: javascript, html

I am making a simple API call to load a random picture on screen when a button is clicked.  I would like the image to refresh and show a new random image each time I click the button.  Currently it just keeps adding new pictures below the current one. How can I get it to refresh with a new random picture onclick without stacking them?  Thanks

```js
loadImage = (url) => {
          fetch(url)
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(newResponse => displayData(newResponse,'dataDiv'))
        }            

        function displayData(apiResponse, divid){
            let gridDiv = document.getElementById("gridDiv");
            const imageDiv    = document.createElement("img");
            imageDiv.id = "Pic";
            imageDiv.src = apiResponse[0]['url'];
            gridDiv.appendChild(imageDiv);
        }
```

```html
<div class="container py-3">
        <button type="button" class=" btn btn-success" id="Button" onclick="loadImage('https://apicall###')"
          Load Random Pictures!
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="container"> 
            <div class="data-grid-container" id="gridDiv"></div>
      </div>
```

Comment: So remove the elements in there

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3955229/remove-all-child-elements-of-a-dom-node-in-javascript

Comment: Or just set the image source, do not append

Comment: [`replaceChild`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/replaceChild) instead of `appendChild`.

Comment: put  in your displayData a condition that if gridDiv has a child with id "Pic" then it should be removed before creating a new img tag

Answer (score 0):

Change your function to remove any children in `gridDiv` and then append:

```
function displayData(apiResponse, divid) {
  let gridDiv = document.getElementById("gridDiv");
  const imageDiv = document.createElement("img");
  imageDiv.id = "Pic";
  imageDiv.src = apiResponse[0]['url'];
  // added code
  while (gridDiv.firstChild) {
    gridDiv.removeChild(gridDiv.firstChild);
  }
  // end added code
  gridDiv.appendChild(imageDiv);
}
```