# Remove options before appending new ones

Tags: javascript

I'm writing a function in plain Javascript where I submit some values via AJAX and if it returns results I need to remove all options from a selector and replace them with the set that's returned.

**HTML**

```
<select id="mySelector">
....
```

**JS**

```
(async () => {
    ....
    const res = await fetch(url, {
        method: "POST",
        headers,
        body
    });

    if (results.ok) {                                
        let myoptions = await results.text();
        var myselectr = document.querySelector("#mySelector");
        myselectr.options.length = 0;                    
        myselectr.append(myoptions);
    }
})();
```

It seems that it does remove earlier options but only on the fist change. All subsequent attempts just keep adding new sets of options.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove all child elements of a DOM node in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3955229/remove-all-child-elements-of-a-dom-node-in-javascript)

Comment: @Spectric It appends just fine. The problem I have  - it does not clear options before appending. It does it only once, the first time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do like this

```
(async () => {
....
const res = await fetch(url, {
    method: "POST",
    headers,
    body
});

if (results.ok) {                                
    let myoptions = await results.text();
    var myselectr = document.querySelector("#mySelector");
    myselectr.innerHTML = ""; // Updated             
    myselectr.append(myoptions);
}
})();
```

Comment: OK, myselectr.innerHTML = ""; actually did the trick!

Answer (score -1):

you should keep currentOptions in memory (not on ui). When you have extra options, you append to currentOptions then render the UI selection with currentOptions again.