# how to stop repetition of previous post

Tags: javascript

In the displayLikedPosts there is a function called getLikedPosts. this  getLikedPosts function filter the posts ID and insert posts into an array. Now after running forEach loop inside the displayLikedPosts ---first time it adds a new and single post(**ex:post-1**) but second time it displays the previous post twice and the new post (**ex: post-1,post-1,newpost**). But my purpose is to display only the previous one and the new posts(ex:**post-1,newpost,newpost2,newpost4**)

```
code

        const displayLikedPosts = () => {
              const likedPosts = getLikedPosts();
 
              likedPosts.forEach((post) => {
              const div = createPost(post);
              document.getElementById("liked").appendChild(div);

              });
            };
```

Comment: Empty the #liked div before re-adding the elements of query it to not re-add duplicates?

Answer (score 0):

Clear thr content inside `#liked` before appending new elements

**Pseudo Code**

```
const displayLikedPosts = () => {
    const likedPosts = getLikedPosts();
    document.getElementById("liked")innerHTML = "";
    likedPosts.forEach((post) => {
        const div = createPost(post);
        document.getElementById("liked").appendChild(div);
    });
};
```

Comment: its working thanks mate

Comment: Please approve the answer if this works for you.

Answer (score 0):

You must first delete the children of your parent DOM node, then add the
elements again.
There are many ways to delete the children, which are discussed in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3955229/remove-all-child-elements-of-a-dom-node-in-javascript). You may find that some options are better (and/ or more modern) than others.

Here is a small minimal example for your use case using `setInterval()` to prove that the list does not contain duplicates.

```js
/**
 * Display posts
 * @param {string[]} posts posts to display
 */
function displayPosts(posts) {
  const parent = document.getElementById("liked");

  // delete children
  deleteChildren(parent);
  
  // add items to the list
  posts.forEach((post) => {
    const listItem = document.createElement("li");
    listItem.textContent = post;
    parent.appendChild(listItem);
  });
  console.log("rendered")
}

/**
 * Deletes all children of a DOM node.
 * @param {HTMLElement} parent parent element
 */
function deleteChildren(parent) {
  while (parent.firstChild) {
    parent.firstChild.remove();
  }
}

window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", (event) => {
  // posts to display
  const posts = ["post 1", "post 2", "post 3", "post 4"];

  displayPosts(posts)
  // call method every 3 seconds to demonstrate it works
  setInterval(() => displayPosts(posts), 3 * 1000);
});
```

```html
<ul id="liked">

</ul>
```