# How do I remove HTML classes created from within a function?

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

I am working on the Etch A Sketch project on The Odin Project. I have created a grid by manipulating the DOM. I want to resize the grid by removing the old grid created and enter in a new one by prompting the user. I notice I cannot access any nodes I created since they are in the createGrid(). Is there any way to delete the created elements associated with my grid while keeping my loop intact?

I tried to have verticalBoxes.remove() in the resizeGrid() however I know it does not work because it is not in the global scope. I also tried removing the container within my resizeGrid() and creating a new one but there ends up being declaration issues due to there being duplicate container variables.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Etch A Sketch</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <script src= "scripts.js" defer></script>
    
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Etch A Sketch</h1>
    <div id= "container"></div>
    <div id= "grid-size">
        <button type="confirm" id= "resize-button">Resize Grid</button>
    </div>
        
</body>
</html>
```

```
#container {
    margin: auto;    
    max-width: 500px;
    max-height: 500px;
}

h1 {
    text-align:center;
}

.row {
    display:flex;
    height: auto;
}

.column {
    flex: 1;
    width: 100%;
    aspect-ratio: 1;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

.resize-button {
    display: inline-block;
    width:50px;
    height:50px;    
}
```

```
let container = document.querySelector("#container");
const button = document.querySelector("#resize-button")
function createGrid(num) {

    for (let i = 0; i < num; i++) {

    let horizontalBoxes = document.createElement("div"); 
    container.appendChild(horizontalBoxes);
    horizontalBoxes.classList.add("row");

        for (let y = 0; y < num; y++) {

            let verticalBoxes = document.createElement("div"); 
            horizontalBoxes.appendChild(verticalBoxes); 
            verticalBoxes.classList.add("column");
            verticalBoxes.addEventListener('mouseover', colorChange);
            
        }
    }   
}

function colorChange () {
    this.style.backgroundColor = "black"
    }  

createGrid(16);

function resizeGrid(newSize) {
    newSize = prompt("What size would you like the grid to be? (1-100)");
    createGrid(newSize);
}
button.addEventListener('click', resizeGrid);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there any way to delete the created elements associated with my grid while keeping my loop intact?

Simply empty the contents of `container` before inserting your new elements.

See [*Remove all child elements of a DOM node in JavaScript*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3955229/2505965) for various ways to achieve this.

The example below uses

```js
container.textContent = '';
```

```js
let container = document.querySelector("#container");
const button = document.querySelector("#resize-button");

function resizeGrid() {
  let newSize = parseInt(prompt("What size would you like the grid to be? (1-100)"));
  if (0 < newSize && newSize < 101)
    createGrid(newSize);
}

button.addEventListener('click', resizeGrid);

function createGrid(num) {
  container.textContent = '';
  
  for (let i = 0; i < num; i++) {
    let horizontalBoxes = document.createElement("div");

    horizontalBoxes.classList.add("row");
    
    container.appendChild(horizontalBoxes);

    for (let y = 0; y < num; y++) {
      let verticalBoxes = document.createElement("div");

      verticalBoxes.classList.add("column");
      verticalBoxes.addEventListener('mouseover', colorChange);

      horizontalBoxes.appendChild(verticalBoxes);
    }
  }
}

function colorChange() {
  this.style.backgroundColor = "black"
}

createGrid(16);
```

```css
#container {
    margin: auto;    
    max-width: 500px;
    max-height: 500px;
}

h1 {
    text-align:center;
}

.row {
    display:flex;
    height: auto;
}

.column {
    flex: 1;
    width: 100%;
    aspect-ratio: 1;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

.resize-button {
    display: inline-block;
    width:50px;
    height:50px;    
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Etch A Sketch</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Etch A Sketch</h1>
  <div id="container"></div>
  <div id="grid-size">
    <button type="confirm" id="resize-button">Resize Grid</button>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Appreciate it, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't [replaceChildren()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/replaceChildren) be an excellent fit for your use ?

Simply store the new nodes you create and then use replaceChildren to add them all while deleting the link between the parent and the old child nodes.

With this solution I believe your `createGrid()` function would look something like this :

```html
function createGrid(num) {
    const newHorizontalBoxesList =[]
    
    for (let i = 0; i < num; i++) {
    let horizontalBox = document.createElement("div"); 
    newHorizontalBoxesList.push(horizontalBox)
    horizontalBox.classList.add("row");

        for (let y = 0; y < num; y++) {

            let verticalBox = document.createElement("div"); 
            horizontalBox.appendChild(verticalBox); 
            verticalBox.classList.add("column");
            verticalBox.addEventListener('mouseover', colorChange);
            
        }
    }
    container.replaceChildren(...newHorizontalBoxesList);
}
```

Note that `replaceChildren()` expects successive arguments and not a singular array of new children, hence the spread.

Comment: Great suggestion, I simplified it even more by just adding replaceChildren() in the beginning of my createGrid()