# CSS grid is leaving black space on the bottom

Tags: javascript, css, css-grid

I'm doing one of the Odin project exercises: Etch-a-sketch.
When I click the button to set the grid size, some numbers leave a lot of black space on the bottom, and I don't know why that might be.
I've read that the fr CSS rule could be causing the issue, but I don't know how to solve it.

```
function setGridSize() {
    gridSize = parseInt(prompt("Enter how many rows/columns you'd like."));
    grid.style.gridTemplateRows = `repeat(${gridSize}, 1fr)`;
    grid.style.gridTemplateColumns = `repeat(${gridSize}, 1fr)`;
    createGrid(gridSize);
}
```

and my createGrid function:

```
function createGrid(size) {
    for(let i = 0; i < (size * size); i++) {
        const cell = document.createElement("div");
        cell.style.width = (parseInt(grid.style.width)) / size; 
        cell.style.height = (parseInt(grid.style.height)) / size;
        cell.addEventListener("mouseover", (event) => {
            event.target.style.backgroundColor = getRandomColor();
        });
        cell.classList.add("cell");
        grid.appendChild(cell);
    }
}
```

Here is a full working snippet:

```js
const grid = document.querySelector(".grid");
const gridSizeBtn = document.querySelector("#gridSizeBtn");
let gridSize = 0; 
gridSizeBtn.addEventListener("click", setGridSize);


function createGrid(size) {
    for(let i = 0; i < (size * size); i++) {
        const cell = document.createElement("div");
        cell.style.width = (parseInt(grid.style.width)) / size; 
        cell.style.height = (parseInt(grid.style.height)) / size;
        cell.addEventListener("mouseover", (event) => {
            event.target.style.backgroundColor = getRandomColor();
        }); // can I write this function outside of the for loop or does the Event object not exist otherwise?
        cell.classList.add("cell");
        grid.appendChild(cell);
    }
}

function setGridSize() {
    gridSize = parseInt(prompt("Enter how many rows/columns you'd like."));
    grid.style.gridTemplateRows = `repeat(${gridSize}, 1fr)`;
    grid.style.gridTemplateColumns = `repeat(${gridSize}, 1fr)`;
    createGrid(gridSize);
}

function getRandomColor() {
    let x = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
    let y = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
    let z = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
    return color = "rgb(" + x + "," + y + "," + z + ")";
}
```

```css
body {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

#gridSizeBtn {
    font-size: 30px;
    margin: 50px;
}

.grid {
    display: grid;
    width: 800px;
    height: 800px;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
}

.cell {
    border: 1px solid black;
    background-color: lightgray;
}
```

```html
<button id="gridSizeBtn">Set grid size!</button>
<div class="grid"></div>
```

full rep if you need more: https://github.com/maverickar/etch-a-sketch.git

Thanks!

Comment: what exactly did you mean by `some numbers leave a lot of black space on the bottom`? it seems to behave correctly the first time you run it, but if you press again the button to create a new grid I think it's not clearing correctly the previously generated grid

Comment: you should `document.querySelector('.grid').innerHTML = ''` every time before creating the grid

Comment: I believe this is because when you go with higher numbers and **then** lower numbers the squares in the grid are not discarded/removed, so they are still there.

You need to redo the squares everytime you `Set Grid Size!`. You can do this by removing the `innerHtml` of the `grid` in the `createGrid` function, with something like this `grid.innerHTML = '';`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue looks like it is caused not by certain grid sizes, but by subsequent calls of `createGrid` (the first one seems to always work fine, but the next calls will produce this black space at the bottom). The black space at the bottom is the borders of the grid cells from previous calls.

The fix for this is simple, just clear the grid before adding new cells to it. I've used what I think is the simplest method to clear the grid, but there are other ways (see: [Remove all child elements of a DOM node in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3955229/remove-all-child-elements-of-a-dom-node-in-javascript)).

Also I've included a few other updates regarding sizing of the cells (lines 12 and 13) and answered your question about defining the event listener function (line 14).

```js
const grid = document.querySelector(".grid");
const gridSizeBtn = document.querySelector("#gridSizeBtn");
let gridSize = 0; 
gridSizeBtn.addEventListener("click", setGridSize);


function createGrid(size) {
    grid.innerHTML = ""; // clear the grid
    
    for(let i = 0; i < (size * size); i++) {
        const cell = document.createElement("div");
        cell.style.width = "100%" // size in a grid is relative to the cell space, so using 100% is easier and works with dynamic grid sizes
        cell.style.height = "100%"
        cell.addEventListener("mouseover", setRandomColor); // yes you can define this function outside the loop
        cell.classList.add("cell");
        grid.appendChild(cell);
    }
}

function setGridSize() {
    gridSize = parseInt(prompt("Enter how many rows/columns you'd like."));
    grid.style.gridTemplateRows = `repeat(${gridSize}, 1fr)`;
    grid.style.gridTemplateColumns = `repeat(${gridSize}, 1fr)`;
    createGrid(gridSize);
}

function setRandomColor(event) {
  event.target.style.backgroundColor = getRandomColor();
}

function getRandomColor() {
    let x = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
    let y = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
    let z = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
    return color = "rgb(" + x + "," + y + "," + z + ")";
}
```

```css
body {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

#gridSizeBtn {
    font-size: 30px;
    margin: 50px;
}

.grid {
    display: grid;
    width: 800px;
    height: 800px;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
}

.cell {
    border: 1px solid black;
    background-color: lightgray;
}
```

```html
<button id="gridSizeBtn">Set grid size!</button>
<div class="grid"></div>
```