# will innerHTML set to an empty string remove child nodes as well?

Tags: javascript, html, innerhtml

In the below code snippet of a random choice picker, what exactly does setting innerHTML to an empty string accomplish. I cannot get past the ambiguity that on doing so we are clearing all the child nodes which are needed to choose randomly.

```
const tagsEL = document.getElementById('tags')
const textarea = document.getElementById('textarea')



textarea.addEventListener('keyup', (e)=>{
    createTags(e.target.value)
})
function createTags(input){
    
    const tags = input.split(',').filter(tag => tag.trim()!=='').map(tag=>tag.trim())
   

    tagsEL.innerHTML = ''

   tags.forEach(tag => {

    const tagEL = document.createElement('span')
    tagEL.classList.add('tag')
    tagEL.innerText = tag
    tagsEL.appendChild(tagEL)
   });
}
```

The code works fine, the child nodes are not removed. Why are they not removed though (going by definition)?

Comment: the `keyup` event handler is going to recreate the `.tag` elements inside the `#tags` container each time a key is pressed. So before doing that it always clears its content and rebuilds it from scratch. By the way there's a typo, you didn't close the `)` when binding the event listener.

Comment: "the child nodes are not removed" - yes they are. For every `keyup` event, all child nodes of `tags` are removed, then new child nodes are added based on the input from `textarea`. This all happens instantaneously (within a single event loop tick). You might hit performance issues with a very large number of tags though.

Comment: i did try it out and it worked fine. i couldn't understand how. hence the question @DarkBee

Comment: now i can visualize it properly, thanks for the help @LionelRowe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> will innerHTML set to an empty string remove child nodes as well?

Yes. Setting `innerHTML` replaces the entire contents of the target element with the result of parsing the given string as HTML. If the string is empty, the target element is emptied.

See also: [*Remove all child elements of a DOM node in JavaScript*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3955229/remove-all-child-elements-of-a-dom-node-in-javascript)

> The code works fine, the child nodes are not removed.

They are, it's just that code immediately after that (the `tags.forEach`) adds back **new** child nodes. You can see that if you mark the old child nodes in some way before replacing them:

```js
const tagsEL = document.getElementById("tags");
// const textarea = document.getElementById("textarea");

// textarea.addEventListener("keyup", (e) => {
//     createTags(e.target.value);
// });
function createTags(input) {
    const tags = input
        .split(",")
        .filter((tag) => tag.trim() !== "")
        .map((tag) => tag.trim());

    tagsEL.innerHTML = "";

    tags.forEach((tag) => {
        const tagEL = document.createElement("span");
        tagEL.classList.add("tag");
        tagEL.innerText = tag;
        tagsEL.appendChild(tagEL);
    });
}

console.log("Create 'tags' and 'before' tags");
createTags("tags,before");
setTimeout(() => {
    console.log("Make their borders red")
    for (const tag of document.querySelectorAll("#tags .tag")) {
        tag.classList.add("marked");
    }
    console.log("Replace them with new tags");
    setTimeout(() => {
        createTags("tags,after")
    }, 1000);
}, 1000);
```

```css
.tag {
    border: 1px solid grey;
    margin: 4px;
    padding: 2px;
}
.marked {
    border-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="tags"></div>
```